# Converting numbers to integers

Tags: list-manipulation, import, excel, number-representation

I've [read](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ChangeTheFormatOfNumbers.html) the [available](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html) documentation [but I](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html) still haven't found an `NumberForm -> Integer` function yet. No result in this site's search, either.

Does it exist?

I should mention: *there are no decimals in my numbers*. They are all integers, which makes me wonder why MMA bothers to fiddle with them at all. Numbers like `84039` get transformed to `84039.0`, and `8048511` to `8.048511*10^6`

---

The problem is I'm importing an XLS file that *should* contain only strings - the fields are set to `Text` in Excel - but Mathematica has its way when using `Import` and outputs a list containing multiple different number formats. Preferably, everything imported by Mathematica would be kept as string, and not converted to `Real` or `ScientificForm`.

Exporting to CSV and reopening with `ReadList` also hasn't worked well.

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7463/121

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `Rationalize` on the result. If your original data is all integers, but with the head `Real` (e.g. `{1., 2., 3.}`) then they'll have the head `Integer` now (i.e., `{1, 2, 3}`).

Comment: Why isn't Rationalize in the documentation (tutorials or how-to's)? That's surprising, but thanks :)

Comment: @CHM Probably because they wanted to keep the tutorial aimed towards the general case. For example, if you use `Rationalize` on a list like `{1., 1.5, 2.}`, then you'll end up with `{1, 3/2, 2}`, which may or may not be what you want. In such cases, you might look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7463/5) for a solution

Answer (score 4):

This is just one of a range of problems in importing data from Excel (don't let me count the ways).... I wasn't aware of Rationalize, but here's a Rule that can be applied upon import to round numeric data:

```
ExcelImportRule = (x_ /; (NumericQ[x] && (Abs[x - Round[x]] < $MachineEpsilon)) :> Round[x])
```

Comment: I had the exact same question,  students sending in answers to test questions in an Excel file.  Very important that some be integers and some decimals.   They would enter them in Excel, but on import,  Mathematica changed them all to reals.  The above rule was EXACTLY what I needed and solved a big headache in my test grading workflow...   thank you!