# Change number from real to integer

Tags: number-representation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this the most efficient way to round approximate integers to integers while leaving other Reals untouched?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/is-this-the-most-efficient-way-to-round-approximate-integers-to-integers-while-l)

Please consider the following:

```
data={123.,56.,45.};
Head/@data
(*result: {Real,Real,Real}*)
```

How do I change the numbers in `data` into integers, so:

```
dataConv=MyFunction/@data;
Head/@dataConv
(*result: {Integer,Integer,Integer}*)
```

**EDIT**

Also interesting could be to change "real" reals like `{12.3,10.555}` into integers by returning only the numbers before the decimal separator `(*result: {12,10}*)`.

Comment: Why not Round[data] and Floor[data] ?

Answer (score 6):

Simply ...

```
dataConv = IntegerPart /@ data;
Head /@ dataConv
```

{Integer, Integer, Integer}

But beware of machine precision:

```
x = 6250*0.292
IntegerPart[%]
```

1825.

1824

May be better to use `Round` as suggested.