# Getting AbsoluteTiming to display in hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: performance-tuning, output-formatting, date-and-time, timing

I'm doing some extended length calculations and was wondering how I could get `AbsoluteTiming` to display in hours, minutes, and seconds. I googled and found nothing, so I borrowed some code, edited it, and wrote:

```
SetAttributes[myAbsoluteTiming, HoldAll];
myAbsoluteTiming[calculation_] := 
 Module[{startTime, deltaTime, result}, startTime = SessionTime[];
  result = calculation;
  deltaTime = SessionTime[] - startTime;
  hms = {Floor[deltaTime/3600], 
    Floor[Mod[Floor[deltaTime], 3600]/60], 
    Mod[Mod[deltaTime, 3600], 60]};
  {hms, result}]
```

This appears to be about .0005 seconds slower than the `AbsoluteTiming` function.

Is that time difference accurate? Is there a better way of doing this? How would I improve upon my code?

Comment: Could you add some detail about why you don't want to use `AbsoluteTiming`? It's not clear to me why you wouldn't just format the first output from that function.

Comment: @dionys No reason, I just don't know how to format AbsoluteTiming. There wasn't anything on it in the wolphram help files, and I'm a beginner.

Comment: The `deltaTimes = 3700;` line looks like a leftover.

Comment: @Karsten7. Ah, yes it is. I was setting deltaTime manually to test earlier.

Answer (score 7):

```
SetAttributes[hmsAbsTiming, HoldAllComplete];
hmsAbsTiming[calculation_] := 
 MapAt[IntegerDigits[IntegerPart[#], MixedRadix[{24, 60, 60}]] &,
  AbsoluteTiming[
   calculation
   ], 1]
```

If you prefer a [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) object:

```
SetAttributes[hmsAbsTiming2, HoldAllComplete];
hmsAbsTiming2[calculation_] := 
 MapAt[UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Seconds"], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]] &,
  AbsoluteTiming[
   calculation
   ], 1]
```

There is a `TimeString` function in the `` GeneralUtilities` `` context that is very convenient here.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

SetAttributes[hmsAbsTiming3, HoldAllComplete];
hmsAbsTiming3[calculation_] := MapAt[TimeString[#] &, AbsoluteTiming[calculation], 1]
```

---

Benchmark:

```
RepeatedTiming[hmsAbsTiming[Pause[0.001]], 30]
RepeatedTiming[hmsAbsTiming2[Pause[0.001]], 30]
RepeatedTiming[hmsAbsTiming3[Pause[0.001]], 30]
```

[image: OutPNG]

Comment: I'm getting: Quantity::unkunit: Unable to interpret unit specification MixedUnit[{Hours,Minutes,Seconds}] when I run the quantity one.

Comment: Here's an image: http://imgur.com/poRDnVM

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed [`MixedUnit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedUnit.html?q=MixedUnit) had been introduced in version 10.4. Based on the syntax coloring in your image, you seem to use an older *Mathematica* version.

Comment: Ah, I am running it on the raspberry pi, so that may be it as I think the pi runs 10.4

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Evaluating `$Version` will return the currently used version.

Comment: I'll try that. Currently in a heavy thunderstorm, so I've got stuff unplugged.

Comment: You were right: $Version returns "10.3.1 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (January 11, 2016)" for the Pi and is up-to-date.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Starting version 9.0, you can use the built-in `MixedRadixQuantity`. The part `UnitConvert[...] &` in Karsten code could be replaced by `MixedRadixQuantity[{0, 0, #}, {"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}] &`.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed Not documented, but this also works: `UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Seconds"], MixedRadix["Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"]] &`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take, borrowing some code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7463) and [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6792/):

```
ic = Function[x, With[{r = Round[x]}, r + Chop[x - r]], Listable];

SetAttributes[myTiming, HoldAllComplete];
myTiming[calculation_, tf : (Timing | AbsoluteTiming) : AbsoluteTiming] := 
         Module[{timing = tf[calculation]},
                Print[StringTemplate["`h` hr `m` min `s` s", 
                                     InsertionFunction -> (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &)]
                      @ AssociationThread[{"h", "m", "s"}, 
                        ic[N[DMSList[SetPrecision[timing[[1]], ∞]/3600]]]]]; 
                If[Length[timing] == 2, timing[[2]], Sequence @@ Rest[timing]]]
```

Some examples:

[image: myTiming example]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and universal function which formats timings (for real-time monitoring of elapsed time one should replace `Round` with `Floor`):

```
formatTiming = 
  StringJoin[{If[# >= 100, ToString@#, IntegerString[#, 10, 2]] &@Floor[#/3600], ":", 
       IntegerString[Floor[Mod[#, 3600]/60], 10, 2], ":", 
       IntegerString[Mod[#, 60], 10, 2]} &@Round[#]] &;
```

Examples of use:

```
formatTiming@1
```

> ```
> "00:00:01"
> ```

```
formatTiming@60
```

> ```
> "00:01:00"
> ```

```
formatTiming[200*3600 + 60*2 + 2]
```

> ```
> "200:02:02"
> ```

```
formatTiming[AbsoluteTiming[Pause[1]][[1]]]
```

> ```
> "00:00:01"
> ```

Benchmark:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
RepeatedTiming[formatTiming[AbsoluteTiming[Pause[.001]][[1]]], 30]
```

> ```
> {0.0010, "00:00:00"}
> ```

Comment: Another way: `formatTiming = StringRiffle[Map[IntegerString[#1, 10, If[#1 > 99, Unevaluated[], 2]] &, DMSList[Round[#]/3600]], ":"] &`

Answer (score 2):

Using Mathematica's built-in unit conversion & getting rid of the annoying "0 years, 0 hours ...":

```
timeConvert=Quantity@@@(Delete[#,List/@Position[#,0][[All,1]]]&[
Transpose[{#[[1,1]],#[[2,1]]}]&[
UnitConvert[Quantity[#,"Seconds"],
MixedRadix["Years","Months","Days","Hours","Minutes","Seconds"]]]])&; 

In[1]:=timeConvert[14695241.8]
Out[1]={Quantity[5, "Months"], Quantity[18, "Days"],Quantity[41.8, "Seconds"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @Karsten's approach of making a pure function that can be applied directly to format results from `AbsoluteTiming`, but if you're new to *Mathematica* this might be easier to follow:

```
SetAttributes[myAbsoluteTiming, HoldAllComplete];
myAbsoluteTiming[calculation_] := 
 Module[{time, result, days, hours, minutes, seconds, format},
        {time, result} = AbsoluteTiming[calculation];
        With[{dy = 86400, hr = 3600, mn = 60},
             days = Floor[time/dy];
             time = Mod[time, dy];
             hours = Floor[time/hr];
             minutes = Floor[Mod[time, hr]/mn];
             seconds = Floor[time - hr*hours - mn*minutes]];
             format = IntegerString[#, 10, 2] &;
             If[days > 0,
                {StringJoin[Riffle[format /@ {hours, minutes, seconds}, {":"}], " +", IntegerString[days], " days"], result},
                {StringJoin[Riffle[format /@ {hours, minutes, seconds}, {":"}]], result}]]

myAbsoluteTiming[Pause[1]]
(* {00:00:01, Null} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Going to give this a try for comparison sake with the other answers to see which runs most efficiently.