# How to select pairs of numbers in function requirements?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How can I get only those cases where the second column has only two decimal places or less?

```
ano=Range[2013,2100,1];
y=ano-1978; 
x=ano-2012;
anoRazao=Transpose[{ano,y/x}]//N
```

The figure below shows the results I want to get:

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string patterns like this:

```
allowed[{_, number_}] := StringMatchQ[
  ToString[number],
  ___ ~~ "." ~~ Repeated[DigitCharacter, {0, 2}]
  ]

Select[anoRazao, allowed] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can improve because I need the whole numbers also...

Comment: @LeandroMacieldeCarvalho like a number without a dot at the end? You can just add ` | DigitCharacter ...` at the end of the pattern for that.

Comment: I thought there was an option in `Case` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Mr. Wizard's modification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7466) of [Stan Wagon's `IntegerChop[]` function](http://books.google.com/books?id=vpYmj7ohofsC&pg=PA30), this can be done:

```
IntegerChop = # + Chop[#2 - #] &[Round@#, #] &;

Select[anoRazao,
       IntegerQ[IntegerChop[Apply[#1 10^(#2 + 2) &, MantissaExponent[Last[#]]]]] &]
```