# Test if number represents an integer

Tags: number-representation

I can't figure out how to test if a number is an integer.

I have found `IntegerQ`, but this function only checks if the **type** of the input is an integer, not whether the number it represents actually is one (`IntegerQ[3.0]` returns `False`).

`Element[3.0, Integers]` also does not return `True`.

I'm probably missing something obvious. There must be an easy way to do this.

Comment: check if `FractionalPart` is zero, or smaller than some epsilon

Comment: Closely related: [(7463)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7463/121)

Answer (score 11):

you can try this:

```
integerQ[x_] := x == Round[x]
```

Comment: One has to be aware of the approximations that the `Equal` function makes, though. `1.000000000000001 == Round[1.000000000000001]` is true, but `0.000000000000001 == Round[0.000000000000001]` is false.

Comment: `Round@Root[1 + 3 # + 4 #^2 + 2 #^3 + #^4 &, 1, 0]` runs into "Internal precision limit". The use of `Round` makes near-half-integers an issue, which they need not be as they are clearly non-integers.

Comment: Although `Round@N@Root[1 + 3 # + 4 #^2 + 2 #^3 + #^4 &, 1, 0]` does not run into this issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
on suggestion of @george2079
checkInteger[num_] := (# === 0. || # === 0) &@FractionalPart[num]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't just use `# == 0` instead of `(# === 0. || # === 0)`?

Comment: @mistercake for your problem it does not matter. you can choose to use `==` (Equal) instead of `===` (SameQ). `SameQ` is usually used to check if two expressions are identical in form. for example `3.0 == 3` will yield `True` whereas `3.0===3` will yield `False`

Comment: @mistercake also `checkInteger[num_] := FractionalPart[num] === 0` will not work properly if you use `checkInteger[3.0]` because `0. === 0` returns False. You can use `checkInteger[num_] := FractionalPart[num] == 0` instead

Comment: Does not always, work, for example `N[E^(-I Pi/4) + E^(I Pi/4) + E^(-3 I Pi/4) + E^(3 I Pi/4)]` yields 2.22045*10^-16 + 0. I and `FractionalPart` yields the same, so this will not be found to be identical to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Define

```
intQ = IntegerQ@Rationalize@# &;
```

Then

```
intQ@3.0
```

> True

and

```
intQ@2.2
```

> False

Comment: I like using the equivalent [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition) version: ``intQ = IntegerQ @* Rationalize``

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if your number mod 1 is zero

Comment: This method has a significant bias in its false positives though. Using `f[x_] := (Mod[x, 1] == 0)`, `f[100000000000.000000001]` is `True` while `f[99999999999.999999999]`. While this isn't likely to be an actual issue in most applications, it is worth remembering that values only slightly above an integer may be reported as integers using this method, while values that are slightly below will almost certainly not be. Every other answer here reports at least one false positive on those 2 numbers though.