# How to correct not precise values

Tags: list-manipulation, import, precision-and-accuracy

I have the source file *file = "test.txt"* with these values:

```
0.008,0.004,5000000.0,4.5329279146e-19,0.0,8.23426173899e-11,0.001,7.75517021273e-11,0.002,7.35362714587e-11,0.003,7.04290905109e-11,0.004,6.83541309162e-11
```

after an import

```
rawData = ToExpression@Import[file, "CSV"]
```

I get the list

```
{{0.008, 0.004, 5.*10^6, 4.53293*10^-19, 0., 8.23426*10^-11, 0.001, 7.75517*10^-11, 0.002, 7.35363*10^-11, 0.003, 7.04291*10^-11, 0.004, 6.83541*10^-11}}
```

This list contains not precise values on the 3-rd place and the 5-th place (the unwanted dots).

I would like to get this list:

```
rawData={0.008, 0.004, 5000000, 0.0000453293, 0, 0.000823426, 0.001, 0.000775517, 0.002, 0.000735363, 0.003, 0.000704291, 0.004, 0.000683541}
```

with the precise values only. How to do it? It is not necessary to use not precise values but I have the source file with these dots.

Comment: Your input and output don't match (e.g., how does 0.0 end up as 1.*10^7?). Also, it would simplify your question if you used `ImportString` instead of `Import`, e.g., `ImportString["0.008,0.004,0.0,4.5329279146e-19,0.0,8.23426173899e-11,0.001,7.75517021273e-11,0.002,7.35362714587e-11,0.003,7.04290905109e-11,0.004,6.83541309162e-11", "CSV"]` so that people don't have to create files to answer the question.

Comment: I have corrected it, bad mistake. Now it corresponds. The values are not the strings. I would like to calculate with them. I tried to import it as a text but I was not able to manipulate it. I would like to use this manipulation:
    `listOfResults[rawData[[1, 3]], rawData[[1, 5]]]=Drop[rawData[[1]], 5]`
and when I call
    `listOfResults[5000000, 0]`
then it should show the rest of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to import some data, and then convert any numbers that are integers in disguise into integers. You can use [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round) for this. First, import the data:

```
data = First @ ImportString[
    "0.008,0.004,5000000.0,4.5329279146e-19,0.0,8.23426173899e-11,0.001,\
    7.75517021273e-11,0.002,7.35362714587e-11,0.003,7.04290905109e-11,\
    0.004,6.83541309162e-11",
    "CSV"
]
```

> {0.008, 0.004, 5.*10^6, 4.53293*10^-19, 0., 8.23426*10^-11, 0.001, 
>    7.75517*10^-11, 0.002, 7.35363*10^-11, 0.003, 7.04291*10^-11, 0.004, 
>    6.83541*10^-11}

Then, use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace):

```
Replace[
    data,
    r_ /; Round[r]==r :> Round[r],
    {1}
]
```

> {0.008, 0.004, 5000000, 4.53293*10^-19, 0, 8.23426*10^-11, 0.001, 
>    7.75517*10^-11, 0.002, 7.35363*10^-11, 0.003, 7.04291*10^-11, 0.004, 
>    6.83541*10^-11}

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7463/121)