# Programmatically retrieving e-mails from a remote server

Tags: programming, import, java, email

Mathematica has a function for sending mail (`SendMail`) and can import the `MBOX` format.  But what I'd like to do is programmatically *retrieve* mail from a Gmail account, from within *Mathematica* on a Windows system.  Is this possible?

**Use case:** I use [MarineTraffic.com](http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/default.aspx?centerx=30&centery=25&zoom=2&level1=140)'s e-mail notifications about ship arrivals to watch [interesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNXVr.jpg) ships as they pass by.  I'd like to filter incoming messages from them and use data from previous notifications to filter 'seen' ships.  I may want to do some automated lookup on ship names too to find those that are more likely to be interesting.  A perfect task for *Mathematica* — if only I could periodically get the new mails and process them!

Comment: What ship is that in the photo?

Comment: Do you mean a [Vowelfail ship](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Flock_of_sheep.jpg/250px-Flock_of_sheep.jpg), for example?

Comment: @acl It's the [MPI Discovery](http://marinetraffic.com/ais/showallphotos.aspx?imo=9530096).  It's built for installing offshore wind turbines.  Some time ago I saw it sail into the harbour while taking a walk in Valletta, it was quite surprising (and this is what motivated me to try to find 'interesting' ships).

Comment: Since Mathematica 10.2 there is a new function called `MailReceiverFunction` which can be deployed to Wolfram Cloud and be used to effectively solve this problem. (Not gmail, but the analysis of email notifications.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've implemented a java program using the [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to only fetch unread emails from a particular user (and mark it as read). This will allow you to periodically get emails from your ship traffic service. This is inspired by [this blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/04/05/analyzing-your-email-with-mathematica/) on Stephen Wolfram's email analytics.

#### 1. Java code to fetch unread email from a sender

Below is the java code, which is saved in the file `FetchMail.java`.

```java
import java.io.IOException                 ;
import java.util.Properties                ;
import javax.mail.*                        ;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm          ;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress ;

public class FetchMail {
    public static String[] UnreadMail(
            String server   ,
            String folder   ,
            String from     ,
            String username ,
            String password
            ) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties()                                     ;
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps")                             ;
        try {
            Session session  = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)                ;
            Store store      = session.getStore("imaps")                              ;
            store.connect(server, username, password)                                 ;
            Folder inbox     = store.getFolder(folder)                                ;
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)                                             ;
            FlagTerm ft      = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false)        ;
            Message msgs[]   = inbox.search(ft)                                       ;

            String[] emails  = new String[msgs.length]                                ;
            String[] content = new String[msgs.length]                                ;

            if (msgs.length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length ; i++)
                {
                    emails[i] = ((InternetAddress) msgs[i].getFrom()[0]).getAddress() ;
                    if (emails[i].equals(from))
                    {
                        content[i] = msgs[i].getContent().toString()                  ;
                    }
                }
            }
            store.close()                                                             ;
            return content                                                            ;
        }
        catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            return null                                                               ;
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            return null                                                               ;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null                                                               ;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, compile the above file. You will need the `mail.jar` file from the above API download. Drop it in the same folder and execute

```
javac -classpath ./mail.jar FetchMail.java
```

#### 2. Calling it from Mathematica

After compiling, include the `FetchMail.class` file in the same directory as your Mathematica notebook. Here's a convenient function that uses this class file to fetch unread mail from the Gmail server from a particular sender

```
Needs["JLink`"];
AddToClassPath[NotebookDirectory[]];
Clear[unreadMail]
unreadMail[server_String, email_String, pass_String, folder_String, from_String] :=         
    DynamicModule[{messages, monthname2num, datelists, parsedate},
        LoadJavaClass["FetchMail"];
        messages = FetchMail`UnreadMail[server, folder, from, email, pass];
        DeleteCases[messages, Null]
    ][[2]];
```

#### 3. Usage and caveats

Usage is fairly straightforward from the arguments. As a sample demonstration, I just marked the last email from you as unread and ran this function and voila!

```
unreadMail["imap.gmail.com", "myEmail@gmail.com", "hunter2", "Inbox", "szabolcsEmail"]
```

[image]

However, do note that

- If you're running this as a `ScheduledTask`, you will have to enter your password as a string argument. Not necessarily a wise idea to do with your primary email ID, but you could always create a throwaway for this specific purpose and use that instead.
- Unread mail from this sender is automatically marked as read when you fetch it. This is necessary so that you don't keep retrieving the same mail again and again. However if you're automating it, be aware that there might be some emails that *you* haven't read and might have missed.

Comment: If it let's me retrieve new mail only, this is a clear accept.  Thank!

Comment: @Szabolcs See my edit.

Comment: Wow, that is really great!  I am going to set up a separate email account for this---the volume of notifications is just too great!

Comment: While this is amazing, I think the JavaMail API must have changed since you posted this code, because getContent seems to return a MIME MultiPart now, instead of something that can be converted to a String.  In particular, your Mathematica code doesn't seem to work (at least on my machine).

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for letting me know; I'll look into it, but I don't promise any immediate solutions. I actually don't know java all that much and this is in fact my first program in it (I learnt the basics in half a day just for this answer). Out of curiosity, does it work for you if you use the `mail.jar` that you get from the linked Wolfram blogpost?

Comment: @rm-rf: I was actually able to cobble my own version together, based on the msgshow.java provided in the demo folder for the JavaMail package. They also have a search.java demo that does some more advanced-type searching. Basically the dumpPart function in msgshow iterates over each contentType, recursively converting them to a string.

Comment: Do not worked for me too.

Comment: @Murta It used to work, but something has changed in the javamail/`mail.jar` since I wrote this answer. I don't know enough java to debug this, but perhaps SteveD's comment above might give a hint.

Comment: If I get something I post here. Tks

Comment: @rm-rf do you know witch version of JavaMail have you used? 1.4?

Comment: @Murta I think I used the jar from the WRI blog. I don't recall the version number... this was my first ever program in java, so there's not much that I remember :)

Comment: So it was 1.4.4

Comment: @SteveD can you share your code? I have the same MIME MultiPart problem when using getContent. Tks

Comment: @posting in 2016 — does anybody have a working version of this? I'd love to be able to check e-mail from within Mathematica without resorting to `MailReceiverFunction` and the cloud.