# How to save a web page in mathematica?

Tags: import, html, internet

For a given web page http://www.nytimes.com/, is it possible to save it as :

> **first**: only HTML(within css)
>
> **second**: more elements(include pictures and so on)

just like what a browser can do.

I have tried this, but it only generates a large picture with plain text.

```
Export["F:\\nytimes.html", Import["http://www.nytimes.com"], "HTML"]
```

Comment: You need to explicitly specify that you're `Import[]`ing as [`"HTML"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HTML.html).

Comment: @J.M. It still doesn't work, give the same result

Comment: Was this question ever answered?  I mean, do you have a solution?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nope, I don't have an answer, but consider using a feasible method of java which I am not familiar with.

Comment: maybe you can use import source and imagelinks and hyperlinks seperately then to StringReplace to Combine them together.

URLSave is another new function.

Answer (score 5):

using Mathematica 9 the easiest way is URLSave

```
URLSave["http://www.nytimes.com" , "C:\\temp\\test9.html"]
```

you get the output

"C:\temp\test9.html"

and then directly from within Mathematica open your html default browser

```
SystemOpen[%]
```

with earlier versions try the following

```
source = Import["http://www.nytimes.com", "Source"];
Export["C:\\temp\\test8.html", source, "Text"]
```

you get the output

"C:\temp\test8.html"

```
SystemOpen[%]
```

Answer (score 4):

I can understand, if Mathematica does not provide such functionality. It is running on top of an operating system, which delivers all the functionality to do these things, like socket I/O etc.

I don't see the point to do this inside of Mathematica.

What you can do is this:

a) unix plattform

```
Run["/path/to/wget", "http://www.nytimes.com"];
```

This is just running wget with the default settings. wget does have a load of options which you can set to modify its result (for instance, if I want to download a webpage and its requisites (css links to other pages) I regularly use *wget -E -H -k -K -p*).

b) windows plattform

In case you don't want to download wget for windows...

1) write a powershell script (wget.ps1):

```
    (new-object System.Net.WebClient).
         DownloadFile($args[0],'C:\tmp\index.html')
```

2) @Bobthechemist found out how to run this on Windows platform:

```
Run["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file c:\\tmp\\wget.ps1 \ http://www.nytimes.com"]
```

Once the webpage is downloaded, you can start to do all the extractions you want to do.

**Edit 1**:

Since I've read in your comments I know that you're about to think of a pure Java solution, you might consider this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class WebPageSaver {
//    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
//      saveWebpage("http://www.nytimes.com", "/path/to/your/home/index.html");
//    }

    public static void saveWebpage(String site, String target ) throws Exception {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(target);
        URL url = new URL(site);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while(true) {
            int numBytes = is.read(buffer);
            if(numBytes == -1) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use one of the many approaches to link this into you Mathematica environment.
Like:

1) [Java-Reloader by Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6376/2448) <-- recommended!

2) [Hands down approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27296/2448)

P.S.: i wrote the windows part answer just out of my memory and i don't have anything here to verify that this is working...

Comment: Nice approach - I don't know powershell, but the script runs fine in powershell; however `Run["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file c:\\tmp\\wget.ps1", \
"http://www.google.com"]` just makes an empty file.

Comment: yes. that's because you need to separate the call to the application from its arguments. since powershell.exe -... does not exist. if Run succeeds it will return 0 for `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: I think it would be super-sweet if I could `Import[ webpage ]` and it would render the whole web page in an output cell of Mathematica.

Comment: @EricBrown agreed...but, i've no idea. on the other hand they do this with `WolframAlpha` calls, don't they?

Comment: @EricBrown really? was thinking about your wishful thinking and I don't get the benefit...why do you think that? because it would show that the notebook interface is able to handle any mime automatically?

Comment: @Stefan For example, I could `Import[ coolMMAStackExchangeURL, "WebArchive"]` into a section, and then I could do some of my own calculations in a new section below. (It would be just like a Wolfram Alpha query). I could save the whole file in one convenient notebook.  Could I just embed a hyperlink to the web page? Yes.  But one could not guarantee the web page would always be there. (I like webarchives on Macintosh.) Also, the content would be available to me offline. How often am I offline? Seldom, but wireless is often spotty. Anyway, many people even want emacs to have an html renderer...

Comment: @Stefan Thanks.  It actually works with `Run["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -file c:\\tmp\\wget.ps1 \
http://www.nytimes.com"]`