# Exporting HTML code to file.html

Tags: export, html

I've got a problem with re-saving html code. Lets create html file:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export[
 "test.html",
 Column@{"Plot", Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, Pi}, ImageSize -> 200]}
]
```

Now, I want to import this file, for example to change some links inside. How to re-export this modyfied code into html in the simplest way? My way is a walkaround but it works:

```
Export["test.txt", Import["test.html", "Source"]]
(*lets skip modification part*)
DeleteFile["test.html"]
RenameFile["test.txt", "test.html"]
```

I do not know html almost at all so I will be grateful for some help.

This question is related to ["How to save a web page..."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13563/5478) wich is also worth looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
h  = Import["/tmp/htmlsource.html", "Text"];

Export["/tmp/output.html", 
 StringReplace[h, 
   a : "<a href=\"" ~~ href : Shortest[__] ~~ z : "\"" :> 
   StringJoin[a, ToUpperCase[href], z]], "Text"]
```

This `StringReplace` expression changes all links inside *`<a href`* tags to upper-case, thus rendering the page completely useless... :).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. This is more elegant and faster. I'll accept this if there isn't any answer of form `Export["file.html", %, "SuperOption"]` :) this evening.