# How can I export a html source string as a html file?

Tags: html

A little question.
Consider one html source string,

```
Export["test.html", htmlsource]
```

Then I get one html file with a whole image of the source.

```
Export["test1.txt", fileToExoprt]
CopyFile["test1.txt","test1.html"]
```

Then I get the result html file.

Is there a direct way?

Comment: Is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26370/5478) what you are asking about?

Comment: @Kuba ah, yes, duplicate :), but glad to know the one answer, I want a `SuperOption` also.

Comment: It seems there isn't such option :( If this Q&A helps, +1 for cormullion would be nice. :)