# How to Open Kernel?

Tags: webmathematica, applicationserver

My MathKernel.exe resides in the following path: C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\MathKernel.exe.

I built a webMathematica application named "WebMathematica" and placed my entire application folder under the "Web-Apps" folder of Apache Geronimo. It's working fine. My Mathkernel was initialized using "mspConfiguration.xml" in the following way.

```
<KernelPool>
  <KernelPoolName>General</KernelPoolName>
    <KernelExecutable>C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\MathKernel.exe</KernelExecutable>
    <URLPattern>/*</URLPattern>
</KernelPool>
```

After this, I copied this entire folder and pasted it in I:\Projects. I opened the command prompt (cmd) and converted my application into a ".war" file.

[image]

Finally, I got a WebMathematica.war file. I then deployed this file in Apache Geronimo.

I started my application server, and here I observed that Mathkernel wasn't initialized, so my application was not working as well.

The problem was the kernel path, the one that I list in the "MSPCOnfiguration.xml" file. I believe that once a`.war` file has been created, we can't access outside paths.

My question is how to fix this.

I never use any `IDE`.

Comment: Since you haven't been accepting answers to any of your webMathematica-related questions, it would seem that these sorts of questions might be a bit too localized.

Comment: exactyly @CoreyKelly ... when i think about for instance on the answer i gave about observing the directory with webmathematica (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27296/2448)...there was nothing....no efforts from my side anymore

Comment: @CoreyKelly I didn't get any answers as per my requirements.so I didn't accepted. @Stefan Thanks for your answer for my earlier question,but it's not useful because every 5 seconds I need to monitor the external file.I thought it's not efficient way so I go through some tutorials, finally I got one solution. we can resolve this using DB service broker concepts and agents.and you wrote `updateQ` function in my earlier question.that one already I wrote in my earlier project.

Comment: You should indicate exactly why a particular answer does not suit your needs. This allows the poster to improve upon it. If you solve the problem yourself, you should consider posting your own answer and accepting it. This way, when somebody else has the same problem and they happen upon your question, they don't find a dead end.