# Using Dynamic to import the chronologically newest file in a directory

Tags: dynamic, image

Imagine that I have a device continually and sequentially saving files to a specified directory on a *Windows* machine (such as [E:\ExampleDir]).  Call this device a camera with some proprietary drivers and software that precludes a direct interface, perhaps via the use of `CurrentImage[]` which works with many web cameras.

Without allowing files to be overwritten, and acknowledging that there will be an associated lag, is there an easy way for me to use `Dynamic` to import and display the image associated with the chronologically newest file in the directory as soon as it is saved there by the device?

Comment: Perhaps something like `Dynamic[Refresh[If[FileDate[..]..], UpdateInterval -> 10]]`, as a start?

Comment: please have a look at here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27296/2448

Comment: Perhaps using scheduled tasks as in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15935/5) might be useful... In fact, if you replace the `Print` statement with an `Import` statement, it is the same question (unless if you insist on using `Dynamic` for some reason).

Comment: It wouldn't be wise to use Dynamic here as it requires that the Dynamic object be visible in order for the updating to take place. You need background tasks  as used in rm-rf's linked answer.