# Running PowerShell commands in Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, windows, command-line

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell command using *Mathematica*. Someone has made it before?

I tested my command direct in PowerShell, and it worked nice, but no idea on how can I make *Mathematica* to call it. Here is a [related answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28698/2266) dealing with scripts.

Maybe the new `RunProcess` can be a nice new function to handler that, and I could better collect the prompted results.

Here is the command I want to execute:

```
git -C C:\somePath pull ssh://git@github.com/myaccount/myProject.git
```

A better toy command is welcome...

Comment: Maybe try as the 'toy' command `ls`, which works in the PowerShell, but not in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Would cygwin be o.k. too?

Comment: Can you explain why you insist on PowerShell? Git could certainly be run from cmd.exe just as well. Not having made active use of PowerShell I think the outstanding feature of it (compared to cmd.exe or cygwin) is that commandlets can return (collections) of objects instead of just "text". If you'd want to take advantage of that I think NETLink would be the way to go, there are several easy to find recipes which show code on how to start a PowerShell-engine and run commands in it and I think it shouldn't be difficult to make these working from Mathematica...

Comment: Well... you can launch a regular BAT file that executes the PowerShell script. But this looks overkill for what you are trying to do. http://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/

Comment: @RolfMertig I never used cygwin. I believe PowerShell is more native integrated with Git, that is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @AlbertRetey I have some problems running git in my server in windows cmd. All work, but I have to import my key in ssh-agent for each time I open a new CMD session, and in PowerShell is works ok. I would prefer so use CMD, my it's not working for an automated task.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino nice link. I will try it. Tks

Comment: @Murta git works just fine in cygwin64

Comment: @Murta: I think the best solution for your actual problem would be to invest in your ssh client config. On a windows client using the putty/pageant combination does work best for me. You would just have to configure git so that it makes use of a ssh-client which asks peageant for the key. I have such a config working but use mercurial instead of git. But I can hardly imagine that git wouldn't let you configure it so that it can also be called from cmd.exe. You probably want to ask that on a git specific forum...

Answer (score 4):

Well, not a PowerShell use, but an example of the new V10 function `RunProcess`.

[Using this link](http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd-agent.html), I did this batch to add my private key in the repository ever time windows start:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==; " %%i in ('call ssh-agent') do (
if "echo" neq "%%i" (
set %%i=%%j
setx %%i %%j 
)
)
cd c:/keyPath
ssh-add myKey
```

Now I can update my git using `RunProcess` as:

```
RunProcess["CMD",All,
"sh --login -i -c \"git -C C:/path/local/repository pull ssh://git@github.com/myaccount/myrep.git\"
exit
"]
```

With `RunProcess` you can have better control over system output using it secont argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `RunProcess` as you have already noticed:

```
RunProcess[{"powershell", "Get-Help"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

Or you can stick to the old fashion (which is basically invoke powershell from cmd):

```
RunInCmd[cmd_] := 
        FromCharacterCode[ReadList["!" <> cmd, Byte],
                "CP936" (*change it to whatever codepage you want*)
          ] // StringSplit[#1, "\n"] &

RunInCmd["powershell Get-Help"]
```

Comment: I cannot get your RunProcess solution to work. It just hangs in there without producing output or errors. I even provided the full path but it still does nothing. The RunInCmd works well. (Windows 7, Mathematica 10.2)

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Hmm... I guess powershell didn't exit, and mma is waiting forever.

Comment: I observe the same as @GustavoDelfino with *Mathematica* 12.0 on Win7 x64: `RunProcess` solution just hangs while `RunInCmd` quickly returns the output.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't have access to win7, but I just tried again on win10 with mma 12.0, it works fine. Maybe there is something different from the OS sides.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of doing it:

```
Import["!powershell.exe \"Get-Help\"", "TEXT"]
```