# Efficient way to list only files (but not directories) in subdirectories

Tags: performance-tuning, files-and-directories

Currently we have a (not very efficient, but still) function `FileNames` allowing to get the complete listing of all files **and subdirectories** of a directory at arbitrary depth. But it has no option allowing to restrict its output to the actual files when directories should be excluded. Hence for selecting only files from its output we are forced to use `DirectoryQ`, `FileType` or undocumented `FileInformation`, all of them don't accept a list as an argument and add significant time to `FileNames`:

```
FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
l1 = Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    Not@*DirectoryQ]; // AbsoluteTiming
l2 = Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    FileType[#] === File &]; // AbsoluteTiming
l3 = Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    FileInformation[#, "FileType"] === "File" &]; // AbsoluteTiming
l4 = Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    Information[File@#, "FileType"] === "File" &]; // AbsoluteTiming

l1 == l2 == l3 == l4
```

> ```
> {7.1199, Null}
>
> {6.98109, Null}
>
> {12.113, Null}
>
> {22.7185, Null}
>
> {20.8688, Null}
>
> {397.981, Null}
>
> True
> ```

**Is there a more efficient way to obtain the complete listing of *only actual files*  in a directory and its subdirectories at arbitrary depth?**

P.S. There are other methods, but unfortunately they don't work in the latest *Methamatica* versions:

```
FileNames[name__ /; ! DirectoryQ[name], $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]

FileNames[StringExpression[
  name__ /; Not[DirectoryQ[name]]], $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]
```

both return a list containing directories with *Mathematica* 13.0.0. With version 8.0.4 they work as expected, but slower than the `l1` method above.

Comment: There is also `Keys@FileSystemMap[# &, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity, 1]` but it is slower for me than to use `FileNames`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the system `dir` command. The disadvantage is that it doesn't allow to specify the arbitrary depth (at least on Windows). For Windows:

```
FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
l1 = Select[FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], 
    Not@*DirectoryQ]; // AbsoluteTiming
l5 = ImportString[
    RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", "dir", "/b", "/s", "/a-d", $InstallationDirectory}, 
     "StandardOutput"], "Lines", 
    CharacterEncoding -> $SystemCharacterEncoding]; // AbsoluteTiming

l1 == Sort@l5
```

> ```
> {7.16807, Null}
>
> {14.5409, Null}
>
> {3.55901, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Another possible way which allows to specify arbitrary depth is to use Windows PowerShell as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13249085/590388) thread. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97511/280) answer shows how it can be used from *Mathematica*.

---

I've tried to reduce the filesystem load by filtering out directory names (found by applying `DirectoryName`) from the list returned by `FileNames`. It didn't gave sensible speedup however because in the case of `$InstallationDirectory` this list contains only about 10% of directories. But when working with network paths it can give appreciable speedup, so I publish here this solution too:

```
l6 = Module[{l = FileNames[All, $InstallationDirectory, Infinity], NonEmptyDirectories, 
     lFiltered},
    (* StringDrop is needed only under Windows! It drops the ending "\\". *)
    NonEmptyDirectories = StringDrop[DeleteDuplicates[DirectoryName /@ l], -1];
    lFiltered = DeleteCases[l, Alternatives @@ NonEmptyDirectories];
    Select[lFiltered, Not@*DirectoryQ]]; // AbsoluteTiming

l1 == l6
```

> ```
> {12.4957, Null}
>
> True
> ```

It should be noted that there are 21 empty and 4181 non-empty directories in `$InstallationDirectory` and 44681 actual files. We are forced to check 44702 filepaths just to remove these 21 empty directories from the list...

Comment: Similar function for Unix: `listFiles[root_] := ImportString[RunProcess[{"find", root, "-type", "f"}, "StandardOutput"], "Lines"]` It finds 42718 files though, whereas the other methods find 42986. By the way, how many files do you have in your `$InstallationDirectory`? I ask because for me, e.g. `l1` and `l2` can be computed in ~1 second. `l4` in 12 seconds. The bash version executes in 0.58 seconds.

Comment: @C.E. I get `44681` filenames with version 12.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @C.E. It seems Unix has its own `dir` utility which has functional similar to `cmd`'s `dir`, but more straightforward syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing the free linux emulator [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on your Windows 7 machine and make sure that `bash.exe` is in your path, then you have the option of running linux commands on all platforms.  Here is an example of counting all the files and counting all the files to depth 2.

```
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/find . -type f | wc -l"},
   ProcessDirectory -> $InstallationDirectory] // AbsoluteTiming
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", 
   "/usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 2 -type f | wc -l"}, 
  ProcessDirectory -> $InstallationDirectory] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.13029, <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "44678
   ", "StandardError" -> ""|>} *)
(* {0.125235, <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "11
   ", "StandardError" -> ""|>} *)
```