# Regular Expressions in FileNameJoin[]

Tags: pattern-matching, files-and-directories, regular-expressions

I'm attempting to create a list of folders that match a particular pattern.

For example, consider I have the following files in a directory structure:

```
a/d.txt
b/f.txt
c/g.txt
```

Now I want to get a list of all of the files that are in folders `a/` and `c/`.
Since I sometimes change work environments, it seemed best to do this with `FileNameJoin`. I use this in combination with `FileNames` to match directories in my structure. I'm pleased with the results when I want to take all folders that match a pattern, because I can use a `"*"` string to encompass all folders. I can use the command

```
FileNames[FileNameJoin[{"*","*.txt"}]]
```

However, when I want to pick a few folders the process becomes more complex.

I would expect something like

```
FileNames[FileNameJoin[{RegularExpression["[a,c]",RegularExpression["*\\.txt"]}]]
```

to work, but it doesn't. Using `StringExpression` instead of `RegularExpression` gives the same error. The issue is that while `FileNames` does accept regular expressions as arguments, `FileNameJoin` does not. My understanding is that `FileNameJoin` must output a string as its result, and `StringExpression` and `RegularExpression` are just not strings. I think that the `"*"` character works because it is a "abbreviated string pattern" as mentioned in the documentation for `FileNames`, but I can't find further documentation of what other characters might be usable for abbreviated string patterns.

I have workarounds that I've come up with that I'll post as an answer, but I'm curious if anyone has documentation for abbreviated string patterns (is a comprehensive list shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6999/57747)?) that might be helpful or a more streamlined solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Specifying folders for `FileNames`

You can simply provide the list of directories as the second argument to `FileNames`:

```
subFolders = {"subfolder", FileNameJoin[{"subfolder", "subsubfolder"}]};
parentFolders = {ParentDirectory[], ParentDirectory[2]}
filesList1 = FileNames["*", subFolders]
filesList2 = FileNames["*", parentFolders]
```

You can use patterns in the folder path specification:

```
patternSubFolders = {"Wolfram*", "d" ~~ __};
filesList1 = FileNames["*", patternSubFolders]
```

> ```
> {"data\\Untitled-3.nb", "Wolfram Mathematica\\test.nb", "Wolfram\\Video"}
> ```

Note that `FileNames` and `CreateDirectory` also *allow* specifying the parent directory and the current directory using the `..` and `.` syntax respectively (but this functionality is undocumented, so I wouldn't recommend relying on it):

```
parentFolders = {"..", FileNameJoin[{"..", ".."}]};
```

They also *allow* specifying that the path starts from root of the drive by starting the path with either `/` or `\\` (on Windows):

```
CreateDirectory["/test1"]
CreateDirectory["\\test2"]
FileNames["/test@"]
```

> ```
> "C:\\test1"
> ```

> ```
> "C:\\test2"
> ```

> ```
> {"\\test1", "\\test2"}
> ```

---

### More info on abbreviated string patterns

> I'm curious if anyone has documentation for abbreviated string patterns (is a comprehensive list shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6999/280)?)

[This](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html#41) is a link to the Documentation chapter devoted specifically to abbreviated string patterns. They provide very limited functionality and there is only a limited number of (quite old) built-in functions which support them. There are only two metacharacters that are supported by abbreviated string patterns. Here they are along with their escaped forms:

| abbreviated string pattern | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `*` | zero or more characters |
| `@` | one or more characters excluding uppercase letters |
| `\\*` | literal * |
| `\\@` | literal @ |

Wrapping a pattern string by `Verbatim` disables abbreviated string patterns.

It is not mentioned in the Documentation, but worth knowing that **if the function supports abbreviated string patterns, they work also inside of `StringExpression`**:

```
StringMatchQ[{"abc", "bcd", "cde"}, StringExpression[("a" | "b"), "*"]]
```

> ```
> {True, True, False}
> ```

```
StringCases["abcd", "a*"]
StringCases["abcd", StringExpression[("a" | "b"), "*"]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
StringReplace[{"abc", "bcd", "cde"}, "a*" -> "X"]
```

> ```
> {"abc", "bcd", "cde"}
> ```

```
StringReplace[{"abc", "bcd", "cde"}, StringExpression[("a" | "b"), "*"] -> "X"]
```

> ```
> {"abc", "bcd", "cde"}
> ```

(`StringCases` and `StringReplace` don't support abbreviated string patterns.)

Also, you should realize that inside of `RegularExpression` these metacharacters have an entirely different meaning.

Note also that `\\` is used to represent literal backslash , and `\"` is used to represent literal double quote "  inside of a general `String`.

As you can notice from the above, there are some subtleties in interpreting the meaning of `\\` in abbreviated string patterns that you need to pay attention to:

```
With[{sm = HoldForm[StringMatchQ[##]] -> StringMatchQ[##] &}, Style[Column[{sm["@", "\\@"],
    sm["@", Verbatim["\\@"]],
    sm["\\@", Verbatim["\\@"]],
    sm["\\@", "\\@"],
    sm["\\@", "\\\\@"]}], "Input", ShowStringCharacters -> True]]
```

> [image: screesnhot]

---

### `FileNameJoin` is not supposed to be used with patterns

> My understanding is that `FileNameJoin` must output a string as its result, and `StringExpression` and `RegularExpression` are just not strings. I think that the `"*"` character works because it is a "abbreviated string pattern" as mentioned in the documentation for `FileNames`, but I can't find further documentation of what other characters might be usable for abbreviated string patterns.

Actually, your use of `FileNameJoin` for composing an abbreviated string pattern is a kind of a hack because `FileNameJoin` is not designed to work with patterns.

> Perhaps a better solution would be to select all folders with `"*"`, then use `StringCases` to pick all structures that match the desired pattern.

Yes, some experiments of mine show that this way is the most reliable when working with `FileNames`, see:

- [Efficient way to list only files (but not directories) in subdirectories](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204261/280)

You can first split the file name with `FileNameSplit`, then apply `Cases` with `Condition` (`/;`) containing `StringMatchQ`, or use `SringCases` with `StringExpression` to select the paths you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Some Examples:

All files with extensions txt or mp3 in folder a or b:

```
folders = {"a", "c"};
files= "*.txt" | "*.mp3";
FileNames[files,folders]
```

All files whose names start with a in all subfolders of dir:

```
folders = "dir/*";
files= "a*";
FileNames[files,folders]
```

All files whose name constains "abc":

```
folders = "dir";
files= "*abc*";
FileNames[files,folders]
```

Comment: +1 for providing an example showing that abbreviated string patterns work inside of `Alternatives`, which helped me to realize that they also work inside of `StringExpression` in the case of functions like `FileNames` which supports them at all.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to make a list of the folders I want to include, then Map the FileNames[FileNameJoin[]] function onto those folders:

```
folders = {"a", "c"};
filesList = 
  FileNames[
     FileNameJoin[{#, "*.txt"}]] & /@ folders;
files = Catenate[filesList]
```

This doesn't utilize RegularExpressions though. Perhaps a better solution would be to select all folders with `"*"`, then use `StringCases` to pick all structures that match the desired pattern.