# How to remove accents from text?

Tags: string-manipulation

I would like to know how I can remove accents from a string. For example, how can I transform `"string test áéíóú"` into `"string test aeiou"`?
I have to normalize some text to make comparisons, and this would be very helpful.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a follow-up question to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14406/57).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove accents from a string I use this function:

```
removeAccent[string_] := Module[{accentMap,l1,l2},
    l1 = Characters["ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"];
    l2 = Characters["SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"];
    accentMap = Thread[l1 -> l2];
    StringReplace[string, accentMap]
]
```

So, if you apply it as `removeAccent["string test áéíóú"]`you get: `"string test aeiou"`

**Update**

Now in version 10.1 we have the native function: `RemoveDiacritics`

`RemoveDiacritics["string test áéíóú"]` you get `"string test aeiou"`

Timing comparison using the new `RepeatedTiming`.

```
RepeatedTiming[removeAccent["string test áéíóú"]]
RepeatedTiming[RemoveDiacritics["string test áéíóú"]]
```

> ```
> > 0.000057
> > 0.000015
> ```

`RemoveDiacritics` wins!

Comment: Ð (ð) is not an accented D (d) but the letter eth without any accents. It should not be considered an accented character in this context.

Comment: Is [`RemoveDiacritics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveDiacritics.html?q=RemoveDiacritics) not yet documented?

Comment: @Karsten7. Almost, [see here](http://search.wolfram.com/?query=RemoveDiacritics)

Comment: You mean in the next version 10.1 ??

Comment: @SquareOne yes!

Comment: @Murta Did you try [this](http://search.wolfram.com/?q=new+10.1) ? 116 new functions ...

Comment: @SquareOne similar. I just used 2015 in the search box.

Answer (score 10):

Your own method without extraneous reevaluation:

```
With[{accentMap =
  Characters /@
    Rule["ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ", 
         "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"] // Thread},

 removeAccent[string_] := StringReplace[string, accentMap]

]
```

Comment: Would a `Dispatch[]` help matters here?

Comment: I don't think so. I have made some tests with Dispatch, and it gets slower. `StringReplace`must already do something like it.

Comment: @J.M. I'll have to test it but I believe that because the String operations are handled by a separate library things like `Dispatch` are not applicable.  At least that's what I seem to recall concluding previously.

Answer (score 4):

Works nicely:

```
removeAccent[s_String] := Module[{patt = "(Capital)?([A-Z]{1})([A-Z]\\w*)*", del}, 
 del = Select[Characters[s], StringMatchQ[ToString[FullForm[#]],
                                          RegularExpression[".*\\[" <> patt <> "\\].*"]] &];
 StringReplace[s, Thread[del -> Map[First, StringCases[ToString[FullForm[#]] & /@ del, 
               RegularExpression[patt] :> If["$1" === "", ToLowerCase, Identity]["$2"]]]]]]
```

Test:

```
removeAccent["string test áéíóú"]
   "string test aeiou"

removeAccent["Çärîñő Ð Štùrm"]
   "Carino Ð Sturm"
```