# What pattern will match accented letters in a regular expression?

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

How should I modify the following such that the accented letter `É` is matched and the expression returns `True`?

```
StringMatchQ["Éta", RegularExpression["[a-zA-Z]+"]]
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to remove accents from text?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14414/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility:

```
StringMatchQ["Éta", RegularExpression["[[:alpha:]]+"]]
```

Comment: On the Documentation page for `RegularExpression` I see only listing of named classes of characters: `alnum, alpha, ascii, blank, cntrl, digit, graph, lower, print, punct, space, upper, word, xdigit`. Some of them have self-explanatory names like `ascii`, `digit` etc. but some (like `alpha`) have not obvious meanings. Where can I learn about them?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov [here](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), in the section, "POSIX character classes".