# Convert quoted printable aka PrintableASCII characters to UTF-8

Tags: import, text, character-encoding, email

I have several .eml email files to import. Some of them were saved as quoted-printable 7-bit encoded.

I skipped through the *Mathematica* documentation and found `ToCharacterCode` and `CharacterEncoding`. However,

```
Import[foo.eml, CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"]
```

does not lead to conversion of the 7-bit characters to the default set (8-bit I guess).

In particular, I want to get rid of encodings like `=FC`, which is a German Umlaut-u (`ü`). After that I would like to be able to proceed with normal text analysis. Does anybody have experience with the right functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had some success with the following function that I wrote a couple of years ago to battle quoted printables on MathGroup:

```
translateQuotedPrintable[str_String] := 
  StringReplace[str, {"=" ~~ c1:HexadecimalCharacter~~c2:HexadecimalCharacter :> 
    FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[c1 <> c2, 16], "Math1"],"=" ~~ EndOfLine -> ""}]

translateQuotedPrintable["=FCberhaupt"]
```

> "überhaupt"

More about this in my [original Stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677257/615464).

The "Math1" argument of `FromCharacterCode` could perhaps be dropped. I used it in the context of the MathGroup where a lot of Mathematica symbols got quoted printabled. For normal text, the default translation should be fine.

Comment: Great solution. What a pity that the Import[] does not auto. convert the characters. Other languages have their function for this:-( -- btw: works with ease.

Comment: Yesterday I found out, that the German a-Umlaut is translated to an imaginary part double-i. I removed the parameter "Math1" and obtained the correct result. Moreover, in my case the equal sign at the end of the line introduced a line wrap at column 75. Thus I changed the 2nd rule to "=\n"  -> ""

Comment: A shorter replacement equivalent to the original is: `StringReplace[str, {"=" ~~ hex : Repeated[HexadecimalCharacter, {2}] :> 
   FromCharacterCode[FromDigits[hex, 16], "Math1"], "=" ~~ EndOfLine -> ""}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & Sjoerd, online converters are giving an empty string for `=00` while this gives `\\.00` which looks like a whitespace. What have I missed?

Comment: @kuba =00 is the NULL character, which in many languages is used to delimit a character string. Whether this should yield an empty string or the NULL character seems like a matter of taste to me.

Answer (score 5):

While I'm not a fan of posting a java based answer when a nice and clean *Mathematica* solution like Sjoerd's exists, over time I've begun to appreciate Leonid's frequent appeals to [learn to "steal code" from Java and use it via JLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6376/5). Your comment:

> Other languages have their function for this:-(

prompted me to post this answer, to mostly serve as a nudge/reminder that in case you're stuck at a problem and know how to do it in of the several other languages that can be interfaced with *Mathematica*, then the most productive use of your time would be to quickly whip it up in language X and use it inside *Mathematica* using the appropriate X-Link application. In that spirit, I'll present the following simple solution using Java/JLink:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];
decodeQP[str_] := JavaBlock[
    QPC = JavaNew["org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec"];
    QPC@decode[str, "ISO-8859-1"]
]
```

Now you can easily use it as `decodeQP["=FCberhaupt"]`, using Sjoerd's example, and it should give you the translated string.

Note that you can't convert directly to `"UTF-8"` as asked in the question and need to convert it to ISO Latin 1 first (credit goes to Sjoerd for spotting this).

Comment: Nice, simple example of a well reasoned argument. +1 :-)