# Importing a VCF file with quoted-printable encoding

Tags: import, string-manipulation, character-encoding

The [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0spy4pk6-qfp16k) has an example importing a VCF address book file which works fine:

```
Import[ "ExampleData/wolfram.vcf" ]
```

> {{FormattedName->Wolfram Research, Inc.,Organization->Wolfram
>   Research,
>   Inc.,Email->info@wolfram.com,Phone->217-398-0700,Fax->217-398-0747,Address1->100 Trade Center
>   Drive,City->Champaign,State->IL,ZIPCode->61820,Country->USA}}

But in my case:

```
Import["F:\\mathematica\\send_contact.vcf"]
```

> {{NameLast->=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95,FormattedName->=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95,Phone->12345
>   678 9}}

How about the `=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95`? A bug, or am I using this wrong?

You can get my `.vcf` file from [this link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/zo1vpe).

---

The ".vcf" file is my test file from a cellphone export. If you import that file into your cell phone you will get a number like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJLbu.png), and if we use `Import`, the following answer is obtained:

```
{{NameLast -> =试, FormattedName -> ="I don't know this item", Phone -> 12345 678 9}}
```

---

Since @bill s mentioned that it could be a missing font issue, I made [another test vcf file](https://www.sendspace.com/file/70grop) with only characters from the English alphabet. The output is normal this time.

> {{"NameLast" -> "test name", "FormattedName" -> "test name","Phone" -> "12345 678 9"}}

**So is the problem caused by the VCF file not being compatible with Chinese characters? How can we interpret** `=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95` **to obtain the original Chinese characters?**

Comment: It may be a text encoding issue. VCF files are plain text: do you know how yours is encoded? I'm on a tablet so I can't check your file for myself... Unfortunately, however, I couldn't find reference to how one could specify an encoding when importing either.

Comment: @george2079 But if you search for "VCF address book" (OP's description) then it's unambiguous.

Comment: @george2079 It is exported by my cellphone.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry,actually I don't know it.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the @george2079 's [suggetion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111637/garbled-output-when-importing-a-vcf-file/111643?noredirect=1#comment303069_111643),I post my solution **from a friend** as an answer,but I'm sure there are more better method can do this.I accept myself answer just for reader.If anyone have post better solution,I'll change the acceptance.

```
$Version
```

> "10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 21, 2015)"

```
string = First@Import["file address"];
Rule @@@ Transpose@{Keys[string], 
   URLDecode[StringReplace[Values[string], "=" -> "%"], 
    CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]}
```

> {NameLast->测试,FormattedName->测试,Phone->12345 678 9}

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for posting this as an answer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plain text of the VCF file from your link:

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95;;;;
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95
TEL;HOME:12345 678 9
END:VCARD

Given this, Mathematica's answer is not surprising. Perhaps the odd characters are representatives of a font that is not installed on your computer?

Comment: I don't think the problem root in the "odd characters".The character I have input is very common.

Comment: What I intended to suggest is that a coding like "=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95" might be a representation from a font that is not being displayed properly.

Comment: Bill, @yode, This is [Quoted-Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, as suggested by the `ENCODING` tag in the VCF. This is called "PrintableASCII" in *Mathematica*. It is a way of encoding 8-bit characters to transmit on a 7-bit transmission line (e.g. the Internet). Yode, you will need some post-processing of your chinese characters. See e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25867/27951.

Comment: What you have are two 3-byte utf-8 characters. Looking here: http://www.ansell-uebersetzungen.com/gbuni.html you can look up the same characters as in your screen dump.

Comment: `URLDecode[StringReplace["=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95=E4=B8=80=E4=B8=8B","="->"%"],CharacterEncoding->"UTF-8"]` work well,Thanks all of you.@george2079 @MarcoB @bill s

Comment: you should make that an answer.  (The `CharacterEncoding` option throws a warning for me by the way, but it works. possible version issue)

Answer (score 0):

out of curiosity I worked out the encoding, at least partly.
It takes the last 4 bits of the first byte and the last 6 bits of the remaining two from each triplet, so we can directly decode like this:

```
cdecode[s_String] :=
 FromCharacterCode@FromDigits[
     Join @@ MapThread[IntegerDigits[FromDigits[#1, 16], 2][[#2 ;;]] &,
       {StringTake[#,Array[{3 # - 1, 3 #} &, 3]], {-4, -6, -6}}],
      2] & /@
  StringTake[s,Array[{9 # - 8, 9 #} &, Floor[StringLength@s/9] ]]//StringJoin
cdecode["=E6=B5=8B=E8=AF=95=E4=B8=80=E4=B8=8B"]
```

> same string

No doubt `URLDecode` is the more robust way to go. Note there are 8 bits that have been ignored here. Presumably the 'E' signifies the start of a 3-byte code - that's ignored here an should be checked.