# KeyPress function in Java's Robot class, how to state parameter?

Tags: keyboard, java, automation

I am trying to use Java's Robot class to type. This is what I have done so far.

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"]
```

The mouseMove command for the robot works fine, but when I try

```
robot@keyPress["KeyEvent.VK_Y"]
```

I am given this error:

```
Java::argx1: Method named keyPress defined in class java.awt.Robot was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The argument was KeyEvent.VK_Y.
```

Calling the function for a robot object using this parameter works fine in a Java IDE, but I can not get it to work in Mathematica. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: keyPress expects an integer and not a string. since keyPress expects an int there is even no method invocation conversion...if your IDE allows you that, then something is going completely wrong...

Answer (score 4):

### JLink KeyEvents

In order to use the static fields from java.awt.event.KeyEvent you need to replace your *VK_Y* with *VKUY*. This is needed, since *_* has a special meaning in Mathematica.

So the letter 'U' is just for 'Underscore'.

Your code will work correctly if you write it that way:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
robot = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"]
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.KeyEvent"]

robot@keyPress[KeyEvent`VKUY]
```

I was thinking about on how to use java.awt.Robot and came up with this idea.
I'm using here the [JavaReloader](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376) package from Leonid. If you have any problems to set it up on Linux/MacOSX just notify me and I can help you out...

Here is a *Keyboard* class:

```
javaCode = "
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class Keyboard {

  private Robot robot;

  public Keyboard() throws AWTException {
      this.robot = new Robot();
  }

  public Keyboard(Robot robot) {
      this.robot = robot;
  }

  public void type(CharSequence characters) {
      int length = characters.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          char character = characters.charAt(i);
          type(character);
      }
  }

  public void type(char character) {
      switch (character) {
      case 'a': doType(KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
      case 'b': doType(KeyEvent.VK_B); break;
      case 'c': doType(KeyEvent.VK_C); break;
      case 'd': doType(KeyEvent.VK_D); break;
      case 'e': doType(KeyEvent.VK_E); break;
      case 'f': doType(KeyEvent.VK_F); break;
      case 'g': doType(KeyEvent.VK_G); break;
      case 'h': doType(KeyEvent.VK_H); break;
      case 'i': doType(KeyEvent.VK_I); break;
      case 'j': doType(KeyEvent.VK_J); break;
      case 'k': doType(KeyEvent.VK_K); break;
      case 'l': doType(KeyEvent.VK_L); break;
      case 'm': doType(KeyEvent.VK_M); break;
      case 'n': doType(KeyEvent.VK_N); break;
      case 'o': doType(KeyEvent.VK_O); break;
      case 'p': doType(KeyEvent.VK_P); break;
      case 'q': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Q); break;
      case 'r': doType(KeyEvent.VK_R); break;
      case 's': doType(KeyEvent.VK_S); break;
      case 't': doType(KeyEvent.VK_T); break;
      case 'u': doType(KeyEvent.VK_U); break;
      case 'v': doType(KeyEvent.VK_V); break;
      case 'w': doType(KeyEvent.VK_W); break;
      case 'x': doType(KeyEvent.VK_X); break;
      case 'y': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Y); break;
      case 'z': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Z); break;
      case 'A': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
      case 'B': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_B); break;
      case 'C': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_C); break;
      case 'D': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_D); break;
      case 'E': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_E); break;
      case 'F': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_F); break;
      case 'G': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_G); break;
      case 'H': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_H); break;
      case 'I': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_I); break;
      case 'J': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_J); break;
      case 'K': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_K); break;
      case 'L': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_L); break;
      case 'M': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_M); break;
      case 'N': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_N); break;
      case 'O': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_O); break;
      case 'P': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_P); break;
      case 'Q': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Q); break;
      case 'R': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_R); break;
      case 'S': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_S); break;
      case 'T': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_T); break;
      case 'U': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_U); break;
      case 'V': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_V); break;
      case 'W': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_W); break;
      case 'X': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_X); break;
      case 'Y': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Y); break;
      case 'Z': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Z); break;
      case '!': doType(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
      case ' ': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); break;   
      default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(\"Cannot type character \" + character);
      }
  }

  private void doType(int... keyCodes) {
      doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
  }

  private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) {
      if (length == 0) {
          return;
      }

      robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
      doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
  }

 }";
```

Using the JavaReloader is easy:

```
<< JavaReloader`

JCompileLoad[javaCode]

keyboard = JavaNew["Keyboard"]
```

And now you can do something like:

```
keyboard@type[JavaNew["java.lang.String", "Just Another Mathematica Hacker"]]
```

And it will write the CharSequence right into your notebook :)

--> **Just Another Mathematica Hacker**

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I was fiddling more with the whole "KeyEvent.VK" mess and saw that the parameter for keyPress and keyRelease is an int. I still do not know why the "KeyEvent.VK_" will not work in Mathematica, but I found this website with an integer code for each key on a standard keyboard and it works when applied to the keyPress function:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

So using this,

```
robot@keyPress[89];
```

actually types the "Y" character, while

```
robot@keyPress["KeyEvent.VK_Y"]
```

still gave an error.