# Is there a way to simulate / spoof a keypress?

Tags: front-end

I'm trying to test the functionality of a Dialog window in *Mathematica* in an automated way. To do so, I need to be able to simulate keypresses to trigger UI elements programmatically. Is there a way to do this from within *Mathematica*?

Comment: You can use JLink, [keyEvents](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26391/5478), [mouseEvents](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30695/5478)

Comment: It can be done, but frankly PITA - easier to use something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).