# How to find longest monotonic sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list, for example

```
list = {2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6}
```

How to find longest ascending sequence of this list?

There are two meanings of this question:

1. Find the largest subset that
   $$
       X_{i_1} < X_{i_2} < \ldots < X_{i_{n-1}} < X_{i_n}
       $$
   where 
   $$
       i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_{n-1} < i_n
       $$
2. Find the largest subsequence that

   $$
       X_i < X_{i+1} < \ldots < X_{j-1} < X_{j}
       $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1**

`LongestAscendingSequence` was an undocumented in symbol in M10.1 and earlier, and has been removed as of M10.2+. In M10.2 the symbol [`LongestOrderedSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence) was added, but it's functionality is slightly different. So, I thought it might be helpful to provide an answer to part 1 of this question that works in M10.2+.

The main difference between the two functions is that `LongestAscendingSequence` returned a strictly ascending sequence, while [`LongestOrderedSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence) returns a non-descending sequence. In other words, [`LongestOrderedSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence) includes duplicates, while `LongestAscendingSequence` did not. One possibility is to define a new `LongestAscendingSequence` using [`LongestCommonSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSequence):

```
LongestAscendingSequenceSlow[list_] := LongestCommonSequence[list, Union[list]]
```

However, this is rather slow:

```
list = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];
LongestAscendingSequenceSlow[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.39408, Null}

On the other hand, it is possible to use [`LongestOrderedSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence) to produce a much faster version:

```
LongestAscendingSequence[list_] := Which[
    Developer`PackedArrayQ[list, Real],
    LongestOrderedSequence[Transpose[{list, -1. Range @ Length @ list}]][[All, 1]],

    True,
    LongestOrderedSequence[Transpose[{list, - Range @ Length @ list}]][[All, 1]]
]
```

And here is a speed comparison:

```
r1 = LongestAscendingSequenceSlow[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = LongestAscendingSequence[list]; //AbsoluteTiming

Length @ r1 === Length @ r2
```

> {1.40971, Null}
>
> {0.098286, Null}
>
> True

**Question 2**

Now, it is also possible to speed up the second question as follows:

```
longestAscendingSubsequence[list_] := With[
    {diff=SparseArray[Differences[-list]//UnitStep]},
    {nzp=Flatten @ diff["NonzeroPositions"]},
    {runs=Differences[nzp]},
    {ord=1+Length[runs]-First@Ordering[Reverse@runs,-1]},

    Take[list, nzp[[ord]] + {1, runs[[ord]]}]
]
```

*(I used the new form of With above, although its syntax coloring is completely wrong)*. A comparison with `longest1` and `longest2` (I didn't compare @JacobAkkerboom's function because it is designed to work for integers):

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000000];

longest1[list] //AbsoluteTiming
longest2[list] //AbsoluteTiming
longestAscendingSubsequence[list] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.504056, {-2.34409, -1.21854, -0.951283, -0.873138, -0.744772, -0.157809, 
>     0.380566, 1.36488, 1.65743}}
>
> {0.096426, {-2.34409, -1.21854, -0.951283, -0.873138, -0.744772, -0.157809, 
>     0.380566, 1.36488, 1.65743}}
>
> {0.035699, {-2.34409, -1.21854, -0.951283, -0.873138, -0.744772, -0.157809, 
>     0.380566, 1.36488, 1.65743}}

Finally, note that `longest2` doesn't work correctly if there are duplicate points:

```
longest1[{1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.}]
longest2[{1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.}]
longestAscendingSubsequence[{1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.}]
```

> {1., 2.}
>
> {1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.}
>
> {1., 2.}

Comment: Cosmetic change to `LongestAscendingSequence` eliminating code duplication: ``LongestAscendingSequence@list_ := 
 LongestOrderedSequence[Transpose@{list, Range[If[Developer`PackedArrayQ[list, Real], -1., -1], -Length@list, -1]}][[All, 1]]``.

Answer (score 23):

1. There is an undocumented function `LongestAscendingSequence`

   ```
   LongestAscendingSequence[list]
   ```

   > ```
   > {1, 3, 4, 6}
   > ```

   This was mentioned [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/58255) and [here in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6148/4678). I hope it will not be treated as a duplicate. I think Q&A-style on SE is more appropriate for this question.
2. For completeness I ask the second question. It seem to be much simpler but I can't find any simple function. My own answer:

   ```
   longest1[list_] := #[[Position[#, Max[#]][[1, 1]] &[Length /@ #]]] &@ Split[list, Less];
   longest2[list_] := list[[#2 - # ;; #2 &[Max[#], Position[#, Max[#]][[1, 1]]] &@
       FoldList[(#1 + #2) #2 &, 0, UnitStep@Differences[list]]]];

   longest1[list]
   longest2[list]
   ```

   > ```
   > {1, 3, 5}
   > {1, 3, 5}
   > ```

   `longest2` is faster for big lists:

   ```
   RandomSeed[0];
   list = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 1000000];

   longest1[list] // AbsoluteTiming
   longest2[list] // AbsoluteTiming
   ```

   > ```
   > {0.925531, {-2.15449, -1.60199, -0.903194, -0.678062, -0.294706, 
   >    -0.270457, 0.219321, 0.677958, 1.07586}}
   > {0.228277, {-2.15449, -1.60199, -0.903194, -0.678062, -0.294706, 
   >    -0.270457, 0.219321, 0.677958, 1.07586}}
   > ```

Comment: I doubt this is "undocumented" in the real sense of the word... it's more likely that it was an oversight in writing the documentation for it. Nevertheless, this is not a duplicate, so thanks for asking&answering to document it! :)

Comment: +1. The shortest way previously known to me using built-ins is `LongestCommonSequence[list, Sort@list]`, but `LongestAscendingSequence` is quite a bit faster. I may add another answer later which uses `Compile`, if I see that it is competitive with `LongestAscendingSequence `.

Comment: For the second one I'd use `MaxBy[Split[list, Less], Length]`, utilizing [`MaxBy`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/12), which is part of my "mental toolbox".  (Note that `MaxBy` will only return a single result even if there are several equivalent maximal elements.)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin did you find that the compiled approach was uncompetitive, or did you just not have time to try it? This was my first thought as well, and it would be interesting to know whether `LongestAscendingSequence` is really as fast as it can be, or whether one can do better.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I just did not have the time. I don't have a C compiler installed on a machine I work with currently most of the time, and the last few months were very busy. Later, I forgot about it. If I don't forget this time, I will test this, and report my findings here - but I can't promise when this happens :)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding question 2, there's simple algorithm finding longest sub-sequence, of elements with consecutive positions, in single pass over given list.

Function generator returning compiled functions, using this algorithm, can look like this:

```
compileLongestAscSubseq // ClearAll
compileLongestAscSubseq[
  {type_, rank_Integer /; rank >= 1},
  comparisonFunc : Except@OptionsPattern[] : Less,
  opts : OptionsPattern@Compile
] := Compile[{{list, type, rank}},
  Module[{start, end, bestStart, bestEnd, len, prev, curr},
    len = 0;
    start = end = bestStart = bestEnd = 1;
    prev = Compile`GetElement[list, 1];
    Do[
      curr = Compile`GetElement[list, i];
      If[comparisonFunc[prev, curr],
        end = i;
      (* else *),
        If[len < end - start,
          bestStart = start;
          bestEnd = end;
          len = bestEnd - bestStart;
        ];
        start = end = i
      ];
      prev = curr
      ,
      {i, 2, Length@list}
    ];
    If[len < end - start,
      bestStart = start;
      bestEnd = end
    ];
    Take[list, {bestStart, bestEnd}]
  ],
  opts
]
```

Let's compile functions taking one-dimensional arrays of integers and reals:

```
longestAscSubseqI1 = compileLongestAscSubseq[{_Integer, 1}, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
longestAscSubseqR1 = compileLongestAscSubseq[{_Real, 1}, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Comparison with [Jacob Akkerboom's `longestAscendingSeq`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136258/14303) and [Carl Woll's `longestAscendingSubsequence`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153763/14303) on list of integers:

```
SeedRandom@0;
list = RandomInteger[10^6, 10^6];

(result1 = longestAscendingSeq@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(result2 = longestAscendingSubsequence@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(result3 = longestAscSubseqI1@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
result1 === result2 === result3
(* {0.041, 16505016} *)
(* {0.051, 25128960} *)
(* {0.0038, 584} *)
(* True *)
```

`longestAscSubseqI1` is over ten times faster and uses almost no additional memory.

Comparison with [ybeltukov's `longest1` and `longest2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34299/14303) and [Carl Woll's `longestAscendingSubsequence`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153763/14303) on list of reals:

```
SeedRandom@0;
list = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 10^6];

(result1 = longest1@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(result2 = longest2@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(result3 = longestAscendingSubsequence@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
(result4 = longestAscSubseqR1@list) // MaxMemoryUsed // RepeatedTiming
result1 === result2 === result3 === result4
(* {0.467, 79999584} *)
(* {0.12, 48000904} *)
(* {0.056, 25131104} *)
(* {0.0051, 608} *)
(* True *)
```

`longestAscSubseqR1` is over ten times faster than `longestAscendingSubsequence` and uses almost no additional memory.

Comment: Very well executed.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it is faster to put everything into one compiled function, but here is a solution using `Compile`.

```
cfu = Compile[
  {{ints, _Integer, 1}},
  Block[{prev, next, startSeq, bag},

   startSeq = ints[[1]];
   prev = startSeq;
   bag = Internal`Bag[{1}];
   Do[
    next = ints[[ii]];
    If[
     next < prev,
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, ii];
     ];
    prev = next
    ,
    {ii, 2, Length@ints}
    ];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

longestAscendingSeq[list_] :=
 Module[{starts, diffs, maxDiff, maxDiffPos, longestStart},
  starts = cfu[list];
  diffs = Differences@starts;
  maxDiff = Max@diffs;
  maxDiffPos = Position[diffs, maxDiff][[1, 1]];
  longestStart = starts[[maxDiffPos]];
  list[[longestStart ;; longestStart + maxDiff - 1]]
  ]
```

This gives

```
longestAscendingSeq[list]
```

> ```
> {1,3,5}
> ```