# How to leave only rows satisfying a particular condition from a table?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, data, filtering

Consider the following table:

```
tab={{1,2},{3,67},{96,1},{1,19},{894,55},{10111,23},{20000,23},{5,93},{5,97},{22,34},{0,1}};
```

How to select only those rows for which `tab[[i]][[1]]<tab[[i-1]][[1]]`? i.e.,

```
tabSelected = {{1,2},{1,19},{5,93},{0,1}}
```

***An edit.*** It seems that one of the approaches is:

```
tabSelected = {tab[[1]]};
For[i = 2, i <= Length[tab], i++, 
 If[tab[[i]][[1]] < tab[[i - 1]][[1]], 
  tabSelected = Join[tabSelected, {tab[[i]]}]]]
tabSelected
```

But maybe there is a faster/more compact way.

Comment: Could you please describe this condition in words? Also please fix `tabb` and `{0.1}` in the desired output to `{0,1}`. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed : thanks! I have modified the question.

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38325/how-to-pick-increasing-numbers-from-the-list

Comment: Readable but likely not the fastest way: `{First@tab} ~Join~
 SequenceCases[Rest@tab, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} /; c < a :> {c, d}]`

Comment: For future users searching for a similar question, maybe "How to delete adjacent elements that verify a condition ?" would help them find this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tab={{1,2},{3,67},{96,1},{1,19},{894,55},{10111,23},{20000,23},{5,93},{5,97},{22,34},{0,1}};
Catenate[Rest /@ Split[tab, #2[[1]] < #1[[1]] &]]
(* {{1, 19}, {5, 93}, {0, 1}} *)
```

It looks like you want to keep the first element, even though there is no zeroth element to compare to. So, you can get that with the following adjustment:

```
Catenate[Rest /@ Split[Prepend[tab, {Infinity, Infinity}], #2[[1]] < #1[[1]] &]]
```

Using a 100000 element random list, AbsoluteTiming gives around 0.15 seconds

Comment: +1 my first time seeing `Split`

Answer (score 5):

No loops using `Position` and `Extract`

```
negativePositions = Position[Differences[tab], x_ /; Negative[x[[1]]]];
selected = {First[tab]}~Join~Extract[tab, negativePositions + 1]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 19}, {5, 93}, {0, 1}}

Which is about 5x faster than the looped method

```
Seed = 1;
n = 100000;
bigArray = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {n, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 tabSelected = {bigArray[[1]]};
 For[
  i = 2,
  i <= Length[bigArray],
  i++,
  If[
   bigArray[[i]][[1]] < bigArray[[i - 1]][[1]],
   tabSelected = Join[tabSelected, {bigArray[[i]]}]
   ]
  ];
 ] (*5.4155*)

AbsoluteTiming[
 negativePositions = Position[Differences[bigArray], x_ /; Negative[x[[1]]]];
 selected = {First[bigArray]}~Join~Extract[bigArray, negativePositions + 1];
 ] (*1.09293*)

tabSelected == selected (*True*)
```

Comment: I realise I did not seed the random number generator correctly here; this is reflected and corrected in my second answer.

Answer (score 4):

One can use

```
Prepend[MapThread[If[#1[[1]]>#2[[1]],#2,Nothing]&,
        {Most[tab],Rest[tab]}],First[tab]];
```

or

```
Prepend[Map[Last,Select[Partition[tab,2,1],
        (#[[1,1]]>#[[2,1]])&]],First[tab]]
```

Both give

```
{{1,2},{1,19},{5,93},{0,1}}
```

in OP's example.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

The new [`DeleteAdjacentDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteAdjacentDuplicates.html) in version 13.1 is exactly adapted to this scenario.

```
tab = {{1, 2}, {3, 67}, {96, 1}, {1, 19}, {894, 55}, {10111, 
23}, {20000, 23}, {5, 93}, {5, 97}, {22, 34}, {0, 1}};

DeleteAdjacentDuplicates[tab, #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] &]
```

---

Using [`Differences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) and [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html)

```
tab = {{1, 2}, {3, 67}, {96, 1}, {1, 19}, {894, 55}, {10111, 
23}, {20000, 23}, {5, 93}, {5, 97}, {22, 34}, {0, 1}};

Pick[tab, Thread[{-1}~Join~Differences@tab[[All, 1]] < 0]]
```

Or Using [`RotateRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateRight.html) and `Pick`

```
Pick[tab, {True}~Join~Thread[ (RotateRight@tab)[[2 ;; -1, 1]]
> tab[[2 ;; -1, 1]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

With `tab = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2}]` or `tab = RandomInteger[10^2, {10^6, 2}]`  both took around 0.4-0.5 seconds.

Comment: Fast and compact !

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability (: . I noticed after that you used `Differences` too and thought that using `Pick` and `Thread` was sufficiently different that it still deserved a spot as a separate answer. To justify the separate answer more I included the `RotateRight` option.  After seeing how some of the best answers use `Pick` on stack exchange I try to use it more. It also looks closer to using the numpy package in Python.

Comment: Yes `Pick` is always very fast, I need to use it more. Your `DeleteAdjacentDuplicates` method is a great find. Wish I could +1 again. Edited my second answer to include the timings.

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability nice I had already left a plus one. I would suggest mentioning in bold at the beginning of the answer that you included the timings since with so many answers here one is likely to gloss over most of the answers.

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability I did not know we completed the 10 fold. There was a challenge earlier this year to give 10 answers for every list related question.

Comment: good point, i have added that in bold to the post

Answer (score 3):

Using the test setup from @IntroductionToProbability :

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 100000;
bigArray = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {n, 2}];
```

Using the `Partition` command to compare pairs of sublists:

```
{t, selected2} = {First@bigArray}~
   Join~(Last /@ 
     Select[Partition[bigArray, 2, 1], 
      First@Last@# < First@First@# &]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

`t`

> 0.258892

```
tabSelected == selected2
```

> True

---

**EDIT**

**Using `Reap/Sow`:**

```
{t, selected3} = First@Last@Reap@{Sow[bigArray[[1]]],
      For[i = 2, i <= Length[bigArray], i++, 
       If[bigArray[[i]][[1]] < bigArray[[i - 1]][[1]], 
        Sow@bigArray[[i]]
        ]]
      } // AbsoluteTiming
```

> (0.393928, True)

Comment: You beat me to it with `Reap` + `Sow`. I think you might get a small speed up putting it in a `Block` and `Do` Loop

Answer (score 3):

### Update: I have included timings for all the different answers at the bottom of this post

Here is an answer with `Do` loop and `Compile`. It has forced me to learn about `Bag` which I have previously avoided as it is part of `Internal` and undocumented.

Excluding compile time it is very fast though, approx 976x faster than the original `For` loop with `Join` and 30x faster than the `For` loop with `Reap` + `Sow`

```
fCompileLoop =
  Compile[
   {{tab, _Integer, 2}},
   Block[
    {tabSelected = 
      Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]](*make the bag hold integers*)},
    Internal`StuffBag[tabSelected, tab[[1]],1];(*third argument 1 says you are stuffing a list*)
    Do[
     If[
      tab[[i]][[1]] < tab[[i - 1]][[1]],
      Internal`StuffBag[tabSelected, tab[[i]], 1]
      ],
     {i, 2, Length[tab]}
     ];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[tabSelected, All], 2]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
fCompileLoop [tab] (* {{1, 2}, {1, 19}, {5, 93}, {0, 1}} *)
```

---

**EDIT: Updated timings**

Functions

```
(* John Taylor original *)
fOriginalForLoop[tab_] :=
  Module[
   {tabSelected, i},
   tabSelected = {tab[[1]]}; 
   For[i = 2, i <= Length[tab], i++, 
    If[tab[[i]][[1]] < tab[[i - 1]][[1]], 
     tabSelected = Join[tabSelected, {tab[[i]]}]]];
   tabSelected
   ];

(* IntroductionToProbability 1*)
fPositionExtract[tab_] :=
  Module[
   {negativePositions, selected},
    negativePositions = 
    Position[Differences[tab], x_ /; Negative[x[[1]]]];
   selected = {First[tab]}~Join~Extract[tab, negativePositions + 1]
   ];

(* lericr *)
fRestSplit[tab_] := 
  Catenate[
   Rest /@ Split[
     Prepend[tab, {Infinity, Infinity}], #2[[1]] < #1[[1]] &]];

(* Syed 1*)
fSelectPartition[tab_] := {First@tab}~
   Join~(Last /@ 
     Select[Partition[tab, 2, 1], First@Last@# < First@First@# &]);

(* Syed 2*)
fSowReap[tab_] := 
  Module[{i}, 
   First@Last@
     Reap@{Sow[tab[[1]]], 
       For[i = 2, i <= Length[tab], i++, 
        If[tab[[i]][[1]] < tab[[i - 1]][[1]], Sow@tab[[i]]]]}];

(* user293787 1*)
fMapThread[tab_] := 
  Prepend[MapThread[
    If[#1[[1]] > #2[[1]], #2, Nothing] &, {Most[tab], Rest[tab]}], 
   First[tab]];

(* user293787 2*)
fMapSelectPartition[tab_] := 
  Prepend[Map[Last, 
    Select[Partition[tab, 2, 1], (#[[1, 1]] > #[[2, 1]]) &]], 
   First[tab]];

(* IntroductionToProbability 2*)
fCompileLoop =
  Compile[
   {{tab, _Integer, 2}},
   Block[
    {tabSelected = 
      Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]](*make the bag hold integers*)},
    Internal`StuffBag[tabSelected, tab[[1]], 
     1];(*third argument 1 says you are stuffing a list*)
    Do[
     If[
      tab[[i]][[1]] < tab[[i - 1]][[1]],
      Internal`StuffBag[tabSelected, tab[[i]], 1]
      ],
     {i, 2, Length[tab]}
     ];
    Partition[Internal`BagPart[tabSelected, All], 2]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

(*  userrandrand 1*)
fDifferencesPick[tab_] := 
  Pick[tab, Thread[{-1}~Join~Differences@tab[[All, 1]] < 0]];

(*  userrandrand 2*)
fRotateRightPick[tab_] := 
  Pick[tab, {True}~Join~
    Thread[(RotateRight@tab)[[2 ;; -1, 1]] > tab[[2 ;; -1, 1]]]];

(*  userrandrand 3*)
fDeleteAdjacentDuplicates[tab_] := 
  DeleteAdjacentDuplicates[tab, #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] &];
```

Times

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 100000;
bigArray = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {n, 2}];

RepeatedTiming[result = fOriginalForLoop[bigArray];] (*10.1189*)
RepeatedTiming[result1 = fPositionExtract[bigArray];] (*1.1596*)
RepeatedTiming[result2 = fRestSplit[bigArray];] (*0.161716*)
RepeatedTiming[result3 = fSelectPartition[bigArray];] (*0.307968*)
RepeatedTiming[result4 = fSowReap[bigArray];] (*0.312946*)
RepeatedTiming[result5 = fMapThread[bigArray];] (*0.299152*)
RepeatedTiming[result6 = fMapSelectPartition[bigArray];] (*0.273186*)
RepeatedTiming[result7 = fCompileLoop[bigArray];] (*0.0103619*)
RepeatedTiming[result8 = fDifferencesPick[bigArray];] (*0.134042*)
RepeatedTiming[result9 = fRotateRightPick[bigArray];] (*0.145216*)
RepeatedTiming[result10 = fDeleteAdjacentDuplicates[bigArray];](*0.128746*)

result == result1 (*True*)
result == result2 (*True*)
result == result3 (*True*)
result == result4 (*True*)
result == result5 (*True*)
result == result6 (*True*)
result == result7 (*True*)
result == result8 (*True*)
result == result9 (*True*)
result == result10 (*True*)
```