# How do I split a list of numbers to monotonic sequences?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have:

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 8, 7, 3, 1, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80}
```

And I want to split it to:

```
{{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 7, 3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}}
```

What should I do?

`Split[#, Less]&` or `Split[#, Greater]&` seems to only do half of the job.

And the Split condition seems only accept two arguments(#1, #2 but no #3).

Comment: Also are you looking for strictly monotonic subsequences? Could there be repeated elements? If so, would they result in a split or not?

Comment: What output do you expect for `{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}`? Will you rely on sequences alternating between increasing and decreasing (which would probably yield `{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {2, 3}}`) or do you want to just pick monotonic sequences greedily (resulting in `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}`)?

Comment: ah..It's lapsus calami...-2 is not part of the second sequence..2 is less than 3 does not mean -2 is less than -3...I feel foolish..

Comment: there could be repeated elements and I will not split at repeated elements unless it is a max or min value.

Comment: both {{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {2, 3}} and {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} are fine, but I'm prefer {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}..

Comment: Please edit these clarifications into the question, so that people don't have to read the comments to get all the details.

Comment: Will there ever be repeated elements in the list?

Comment: In the example you have right now ({1,2,4,5,7,11,8,7,3,1,-3,-2,6,7,80}), the 11 could fit into either the first or 2nd set. Your goal has it in the 1st set, so do you want it to be a greedy algorithm like Martin said? Same goes for the -3, I think.

Comment: @YungHummmma  In the real cases every monotonic subsequent in the list would be quite long, so I don't care about the border  elements. It's OK  to put them into either adjacent subsequents or both of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting at 10.1, there's a fairly neat solution using [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 8, 7, 3, 1, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80};
SequenceCases[list, x_ /; Less @@ x || Greater @@ x]
(* {{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 7, 3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}} *)
```

This works because `SequenceCases` defaults to `Overlaps -> False`, such that e.g. `11` won't appear in two of the sublists.

Of course, if you want to allow repeated elements (i.e. not *strictly* monotonic sequences), use `LessEqual` and `GreaterEqual` respectively.

For a pre-10.1 solution using `Split` [see Xavier's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113827/2305).

Answer (score 11):

[Martin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2305/martin-b%C3%BCttner) provided a nice [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113821/31159) with [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html). For *Mathematica* versions prior to 10.1, depending on what OP wants for lists of the form:

```
list2 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 8, 9, 10, 12, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80};
```

namely, for lists that have consecutive sequences of same monotonicity, an approach could be:

```
splitMon[list_] := 
    Split[list, 
        sign =.; 
        If[sign (#2 - #1) > 0, True, sign =.; False, sign = Sign[#2 - #1]; True] &
    ];
```

Examples:

```
SequenceCases[list, x_ /; Less @@ x || Greater @@ x]
% === splitMon[list]

(* {{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 7, 3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}} *)
(* True *)

SequenceCases[list2, x_ /; Less @@ x || Greater @@ x]
% === splitMon[list2]

(* {{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 9, 10, 12}, {-3, -2, 6, 7, 80}} *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using `SplitBy`. It works also for elements that are repeated no more than once, but it can be fixed if there are elements repeated more than once.

```
monotonicSplit[list_] := SplitBy[Transpose[{#, {#1, ##} & @@ Sign@Differences@#}] &@list, Last][[All, All, 1]]

list = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 1, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80};
monotonicSplit[list]
(* {{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {6}, {7}, {3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive way:

```
ClearAll[monoSplit];
monoSplit[{pre___, a_, b_, c_, post___}] /; (a < b && b > c) || (a > b && b < c) :=Sequence[{pre, a, b}, monoSplit[{c, post}]];
monoSplit[{pre___, a_, b_, c_, post___}] := {pre, a, b, c,  post};
monoSplit[{a_}] := {a};
```

and, in action:

```
monoSplit@{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 8, 7, 3, 1, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80}//List
(* Out *) {{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 7, 3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same method I used for [Partitioning a list when the cumulative sum exceeds 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105792/121).

As there my emphasis is on elegance rather than ultimate performance.

*Cleaner now!*

```
fn[a_List] :=
  Module[{o},
    Split[a, o # < o #2 || (o = #2 - #) &]
  ]

{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11, 8, 7, 3, 1, -3, -2, 6, 7, 80} // fn
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 11}, {8, 7, 3, 1, -3}, {-2, 6, 7, 80}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `Compile`

```
cfu3 = Compile[
  {{ints, _Integer, 1}},
  Block[{prev, next, startSeq, bag, sign},
   sign = 1;
   startSeq = ints[[1]];
   prev = startSeq;
   bag = Internal`Bag[{1}];
   Do[
    next = ints[[ii]];
    If[
     sign*next < sign*prev,
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, ii];
     sign *= -1;
     ];
    prev = next
    ,
    {ii, 2, Length@ints}
    ];
   Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
   ]
  ,
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

monotoneSequences[list_] := 
 Module[{starts, ends, maxDiff, maxDiffPos, longestStart},
  starts = cfu3[list];
  ends = starts + 
    Append[Differences[starts] - 1, Length[list] - starts[[-1]]];
  MapThread[list[[# ;; #2]] &, {starts, ends}]
  ]
```

Which gives

```
monotoneSequences[list]
```

> ```
> {{1,2,4,5,7,11},{8,7,3,1,-3},{-2,6,7,80}}
> ```

Use `cfu` (instead of `cfu3`) from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136258/4330) to get only the ascending sequences.