# Find sequence of minima

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

This is related (in my mind, but probably not in terms of solutions) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126184/find-longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-containing-final-two-elements).

Given a list, I'd like to first find the minimum element (or the leftmost such if there are two); then, among the rest of the list to the right of the found element, the minimum of what remains. Continue until there is only one element left. Thus for example given `{7,2,5,3,4,8}` the result would be `{2,3,4,8}` (`2` is the minimum. After removing `7` and `2`, you are left with `{5,3,4,8}`, of which `3` is the minimum. Continue.) Given `{4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 8}` the result would be `{2,3,5,5,8}`.

It appears that I could use `Min` together with `Position` and iterate over the list, removing elements to the left of the last found peak, but is there a more efficient way? (These will be pretty long lists).

Comment: It would be nice to see your own effort(s) presented in the question. In general, this is not a "do this for me" site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 8};
Module[{x = 1, ord = Ordering@list},
 list[[
   Reap[
     Scan[
      If[# > x, Sow[x = #]] &,
      ord]
     ][[2, 1]]
   ]]
 ]
(* {2, 3, 5, 5, 8} *)
```

This code by Xavier works similarly (and with similar timing), by going through the elements one-by-one and keeping track of the current lowest-value, but uses `Map` instead of `Scan`, `Reap`, and `Sow`

```
Reverse@Map[x = list[[-1]]; If[# <= x, x = #, Nothing] &, Reverse@list]
```

The above methods are fairly quick, but for efficiency this method by MichaelE2 wins the prize:

```
list[[DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[Max, Ordering@list]]
```

Comment: +1. This is a bit faster: `list[[First /@ Tally@ FoldList[Max, Ordering@list]]]`.

Comment: @Xavier In my mind, it is still Jason's algorithm, just with a fast `Max` replacing a slow `If` tossed with a bit of "immutability," if I understand that term correctly.  My hope was that he'd include it in his answer.  But if he doesn't want to, I will post it later.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I was going to say that the only similarity between yours and mine is the final call to `Part`, but then I really examined it and I can see the similarity more.  I can add it here if you like (I *have* been slacking off here since I got a real job, my [fake internet points](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/41fa4y/why_do_you_care_about_fake_internet_points/) tally is no longer growing like it used to)

Comment: This has the same speed, but it's clearer, imo: `list[[DeleteDuplicates@FoldList[Max, Ordering@list]]]`.  I suppose it's arguable whether the idea for an algorithm or for the code refactoring should be considered more deserving of points on a site devoted to both. I've got enough f.i.p.s, so feel free to incorporate it, if you're comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 8};

minimas[list_] := Block[{a, out, f, min, pos},
  a = list;
  out = {};
  f := Module[{},
    min = First@TakeSmallest[a, 1];
    AppendTo[out, min];
    pos = First@Flatten@Position[a, min];
    a = Drop[a, pos]
    ];
  While[Length@a > 0, f];
  out
  ]

minimas[a]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 5, 8}

The timing is also acceptable:

```
b = RandomInteger[100, 100000];
minb = minimas[b]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.69, Null}

```
Length @ minb
```

> 989

---

```
c = RandomInteger[1000, 100000];
minc = minimas[b]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.12, Null}

```
Length @ minc
```

> 86