# Generalizing LongestCommonSequence to 3 or more arguments?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming, algorithm, combinatorics

The function [`LongestCommonSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSequence.html) finds a [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) between 2 lists. Apparently, this built-in function does not accept more than 2 arguments. How can I find a longest common subsequence between 3 or more lists using *Mathematica*? Or, better yet, all longest common subsequences?

---

*In a response to a "close as a duplicate" vote:* This is not a duplicate of [Longest common substring for multiple strings?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114979/longest-common-substring-for-multiple-strings) beacuse that question is concerned with substrings (contiguous subsequences), but my question is concerned with arbitrary (not necessarily contiguous) subsequences.

Comment: Related: mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114987/9490

Comment: actually this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114987/2079 works by first converting strings to list and so contains exactly an answer to this question.

Comment: @george2079 It is interesting, but seems to be slow as hell. Besides, I have a hunch that the complexity of even the best algorithm here would be proportional to the product of lists lengths, or something like that. So it is basically quadratic for 2  similarly sized lists, cubic for 3, and so on. Can't prove it though.

Comment: @george2079 No, this is not a duplicate, as I explained in an addendum to the question.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "not necessarily contiguous", or maybe give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @xslittlegrass The Wikipedia page I linked provides detailed definitions an examples. Let $S$ be a string or a list. A subsequence of $S$ is obtained by removing zero or more elements of $S$ at arbitrary positions (e.g. `"tea"`, `"aha"` and `"etc"` are subsequences of `"Mathematica"`). A substring of $S$ is a prefix of a suffix of $S$ (e.g. `"them"` is a substring of `"Mathematica"`, because it is a prefix of its suffix `"thematica"`). Every substring is also a subsequence.

Comment: you ask to "generalize" `LongestCommonSequence` to 3 or more arguments, but you also want to generalize to a different definition of sequence? Please give a clear definition of terms and an example to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why my definition is different. Different from what?

Answer (score 8):

```
ClearAll[fuzzyLCS];
fuzzyLCS[strings__List] :=
 Module[
  {subsets, aligned, intersections},
  subsets = Subsets[strings, {2, Length@strings}];
  aligned = 
   Select[SequenceAlignment[#[[1]], #[[2]]], StringQ[#] &] & /@ 
    subsets;
  intersections = 
   Intersection @@ (Subsets[#, {1, 
         Length@#}] & /@ (Flatten[Characters[#]] & /@ aligned));
  StringJoin[SortBy[intersections, Length] // Last]
  ]

fuzzyLCS[{"theano", "mathematica", "matea"}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000150089, "tea"}