# Convert Java code to Mathematica

Tags: import

This is in reference to this question from Math SE: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779109/how-can-i-calculate-oeis-a144311-efficiently).

Is there a way to import Java code into Mathematica? I'm looking for either:

1. A conversion utility
2. A method of manually converting
3. A way for me to at least implement, edit, and run the code without having to learn Java.

My main objective would be to have a definite method of converting code like from the answer to this question ([here](https://gist.github.com/joriki/61860c6d85853d39f6b470ec0c42e290)) to a Mathematica notebook as I know how to work with Mathematica and have a raspberry pi, but don't know Java. What's the best way to do this? Or, if there's not a simple conversion method, what would the code be? Are there certain things I can look for in Java that correspond to things in Mathematica, or would the conversion require a high knowledge of both codes inner workings?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to convert it automatically.  You can either 1) implement the same algorithm described in the Math.SE answer (this will run much slower than Java) or 2) use [J/Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html) to call the Java program from Mathematica.  Asking people to convert the code is not appropriate for this site ...

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try J/Link out. That's really what I was looking for: a) a conversion utility, b) a method of manually converting, or c) a way for me to at least implement the code, edit, and run without learning Java.

Comment: Well, you'll need to learn at least a *little* bit of Java to use J/Link, but not much.  I know next to zero Java but I did use J/Link for small things a few times.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6376/1364) maybe useful.

Comment: Instead of closing, perhaps @Szabolcs's comment could be an answer.  This seems like a question others might want to know the answer to, even if it is negative (or half-positive if you think J/Link is a solution).