# How to scramble a string of text?

Tags: string-manipulation

How to implement `foo` function which works like this:

```
foo @ "abcdef"
```

> ```
> "fdbace"
> ```

Steps: `"bacdef", "cabdef", "dbacef", "ecabdf", "fdbace"`

Reverse the first two letter of the string `"abcdef"` which will give `"bacdef"`. Then take this as the new string and reverse the first 3 letter. Similarly, proceed for all the characters of the string.

Comment: OK, I gotta say this: are you seriously asking this place to solve [Pancake Scramble](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/pancake-scramble)? Your questions are starting to form a pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for "Longest Common Substring" solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
s = "abcdef";

FoldList[
 StringJoin[
   StringReverse[StringTake[#1, {1, #2}]],
   StringTake[#1, {#2 + 1, -1}]
   ] &,
 s,
 Range[2, StringLength[s]]
 ]
```

> {"abcdef", "bacdef", "cabdef", "dbacef", "ecabdf", "fdbace"}

Comment: I'm actually surprised at how efficient this is. I would have assumed the fastest way would be to work on the `ToCharacterCode` processed byte data in some in-place way but this is actually much faster, even without all of the `FromCharacterCode` post-processing. On a string of length 5000 it's actually faster even than in place reversal of the bytes themselves in an array which *really* surprised me. To add to that, it's even faster than the corresponding code using `Reverse` and `Part` on the list of bytes which has all sorts of odd implications.

Comment: @b3m3a1 Yeah, I was also somewhat surprised  when I tried to optimize the code. Usually, String operations in Mathematice tend to be rather slow...

Comment: I wonder what part is the real holdup. I'm really surprised that working with packed arrays of integers is slower than working with strings. Also it seems writing your solution with `StringDrop` is also slower than `StringTake[#1, {#2 + 1 ;;}]` which is again very surprising. The specially made operation should be the fastest one, to my eyes.

Comment: It turns out [String is really fast now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182904/38205)

Answer (score 3):

```
FoldList[StringReplace[#,  StartOfString ~~ p : Repeated[_, {#2}] :> 
  StringReverse[p]] &, "abcdef" , Range[2, 6]]
```

> {"abcdef", "bacdef", "cabdef", "dbacef", "ecabdf", "fdbace"}

Also

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[k_] := Module[{c = TakeDrop[Characters[#], k]}, 
   StringJoin[c[[1]][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -2]], c[[1]][[1 + Boole[OddQ[k]] ;; ;; 2]], c[[2]]] ] &
f2 = Table[f1[k]@# , {k, StringLength @ #}] &;

f2 @ "abcdef"
```

> {"abcdef", "bacdef", "cabdef", "dbacef", "ecabdf", "fdbace"}

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
Block[{k = 1, s = "abcdef"},
      NestList[StringReplacePart[#, StringReverse[StringTake[#, ++k]], {1, k}] &,
               s, StringLength[s] - 1]]
   {"abcdef", "bacdef", "cabdef", "dbacef", "ecabdf", "fdbace"}
```