# What changed in String handling between 11.0 and 11.3?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, string-manipulation, packed-arrays

I was trying to optimize some `String`-handling code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182894/38205) using my standard trick of converting it to a list of bytes first and using basic list operations instead of the string ones as `String*` operations *used* to be very slow.

To my surprise, working with a `String` is now, amazingly, faster than working with a packed array if you only need to do things like `Reverse` or `Take`.

When I looked deeper into what was happening it turns out `String` is as fast or faster for atomic operations than a packed array of ints is, now.

#### 11.0 Benchmarks

Here's the 11.0 benchmarking:

```
inpString =
  BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[0];
   StringJoin@RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 250000]
   ];

inpString // ByteCount

250080

strDats = {#, 
     Mean@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[StringTake[inpString, {#}]], 
       250]} & /@ Range[1, StringLength@inpString, 500];

strDats // ListPlot
```

[image: blarf]

```
bytes = ToCharacterCode@inpString;

bytes // ByteCount

2000144

byteDats = {#, First@RepeatedTiming@bytes[[#]]} & /@ 
   Range[1, Length@bytes, 500];

byteDats // ListPlot
```

[image]

And `StringTake` was incredibly slow relative to `Take`:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[0];
  ranges = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{1, Length@byteDats}, {500, 2}]
  ];

Map[StringTake[inpString, #] &, ranges] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.539

Map[Take[bytes, #] &, ranges] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00071
```

#### 11.3 Results

```
inpString =
  BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[0];
   StringJoin@RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 250000]
   ];

inpString // ByteCount

250072

strDats = {#, First@RepeatedTiming[StringTake[inpString, {#}]]} & /@ 
   Range[1, StringLength@inpString, 500];

strDats // ListPlot
```

[image: 1111111]

```
bytes = ToCharacterCode@inpString;

bytes // ByteCount

2000144

byteDats = {#, First@RepeatedTiming@bytes[[#]]} & /@ 
   Range[1, Length@bytes, 500];

byteDats // ListPlot
```

[image]

And we see first off that all these element taking operations in `String` are now much faster. And secondly, it turns out they are ever so slightly faster than the packed array version:

```
Mean@strDats[[All, 2]]

3.4*10^-7

Mean@byteDats[[All, 2]]

3.8*10^-7
```

And `StringTake` is now competitive with `Take`:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[0];
  ranges = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{1, Length@byteDats}, {500, 2}]
  ];

Map[StringTake[inpString, #] &, ranges] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00074

Map[Take[bytes, #] &, ranges] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.00065
```

this combined with the memory efficiency of `String` means that it can sometimes now be faster to work with strings instead of lists of ints which is wild.

#### Questions

That was a lot of prologue, but here are my questions:

1. When did this happen?
2. Is there a case where instead of working with a list of ints I should work with the (absolutely meaningless) string instead?
3. How did this happen? (this may be under NDA or something, but I'd be really interested to hear about the internal restructuring that clearly had to take place).

Comment: Hm. In principle, a classical string requires less memory than its integer list form (a `char` needs 1 Byte, a Mathematica integer 8 Byte). So, if a Mathematica `String` stores not only the array of characters but also its lenghts, it is pretty much like a packed array but with one eigth of the size. This would allow to speed up memory bound operations like copying. So in this respect, `Strings` _should_ actually be faster than packed arrays. It is really good to see that Mathematica is approaching this ideal state...