# The i-th element of a permutation

Tags: permutation

I am trying to run something of the form

```
p = Permutations[Range[1,16]];
result={};
Table[If["p[[i]] satisfies some conditions",result=Append[result,p[[i]]]],{i,1,Length[[p]]}];
```

and I get an "out of memory error" when defining p. I am trying to find a way around this, especially since I don't really need to store Permutations[Range[1,16]] at any given point. All I want is access the i-th element of it and run some tests (for all i). I understand this might take ages but I can afford to let the program run for months, whereas the memory of the computer I am using is restricted. Any ideas?

---

A "proper" minimal example:

```
p = Permutations[Range[1,16]];
result={};
Table[If[p[[i]]==Range[1,16],result=Append[result,p[[i]]]],{i,1,Length[p]}];
result
```

and the expected output would be {1,2,3,4,..,16}.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of: [(1283)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1283).  See also: [(21584)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21584)

Comment: very strange: Length[[p]]

Comment: p becomes too big (first line)

Comment: Could you give us the explicit conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it. You can use the [`` Combinatorica` ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/guide/CombinatoricaPackage.html) package. Either the function [`NextPermutation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/NextPermutation.html) which allows you to iterate over the permutations or the function [`UnrankPermutation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/UnrankPermutation.html) which does exactly what is described.

Answer (score 0):

### You may use package Combinatorica` to get a specific permutation

Length[[p]] is an error, should be Length[p]

Just for fun:

Let's calculate the memory needed to store your list in Mathematica

Calculating the number of permutations possible

```
15!

1307674368000
```

Bytes needed to store a single permutation

```
ByteCount[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}]

416


15! *416 /2^30 //N
506632.5302124023
```

So about 500 Terrabytes are needed to store your expression in Mathematica.

Comment: That is why the OP is asking for a way to go through the permutations without loading all permutations into the memory....

Comment: Bringing 15 Integers in a different order shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Your new answer in bold at the top is not right either. At least in V10 `Permute` has been moved to MMA, so you don't need the Combinatorica package to use it. But that's not even the right function, which is what Heterotic posted.

Comment: I really have to get MMA10 now, thx