# Generating a permutation of elements in chunks

Tags: functions, permutation

Is there a way for me to generate a list of permutations in "chunks" such that I needn't store everything on RAM all at once?

Consider that (WARNING: DO NOT RUN! --- Will generate a list with 13! = 6,227,020,800 entries!)

```
Permutations[{"t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11","t12","t13"}]
```

Will obviously not be storable on a standard personal computer.

However, is there a way for me to ask Mathematica for the a "chunk" of permutations with indices $n_1$ through $n_2$ where, hypothetically if we had the output for Permutations above, $n_1$ would be the index of the first element in the chunk we ask for and $n_2$ would be the index of the last element in the chunk we ask for?

For example:

```
smallEx=Permutations[{"t1","t2","t3"}];
```

Gives the output:

```
{{"t1", "t2", "t3"}, {"t1", "t3", "t2"}, {"t2", "t1", "t3"}, {"t2", "t3", "t1"}, {"t3", "t1", "t2"}, {"t3", "t2", "t1"}};
```

I was hoping for some way to write a function like:

```
PermutationChunk[{"t1","t2","t3"}, {3,5}]
```

That in this case, with $(n_1,n_2)$ = {3,5}, would return:

```
{{"t2", "t1", "t3"}, {"t2", "t3", "t1"}, {"t3", "t1", "t2"}}
```

Or a single permutation for:

```
PermutationChunk[{"t1","t2","t3"}, {2,2}]
```

Out:

```
{"t1", "t3", "t2"}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Have a look at `Subsets`.

Comment: You can break up your set S into a partition S_1 and S_2 with S_1 /union S_2 = S. Calculate the permutations of S_i and from that build up the total number of permutations chunk by chunk.

Comment: Closely related or possible duplicate: [(1283)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1283/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the relevant mathematics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string) and below is my attempt at coding it in mma.

```
main[list_, pos_] := 
Module[{f, r, len, fr1, fr2, index, finalresult},

len = (Length[list] - 1);
finalresult = {};
f[num_, fac_] := Module[{res},
 res = 
  Solve[(num == q*fac! + r) && q >= 0 && 0 < r <= fac!, {q, r}, 
   Integers];
 finalresult = Join[{finalresult, res[[1, 1, 2]] + 1}];
 res[[1, 2, 2]]
 ];
 FoldList[f, pos, Range[len, 0, -1]];
 index = Flatten[finalresult];

 fr1 = {};
 r[l_, ind_] := Module[{},
 fr2 = Take[l, {ind}];
 fr1 = Join[{fr1, fr2}];
 Sort[Drop[l, {ind}]]
 ];
FoldList[r, list, index];
 Flatten[fr1]
 ];
```

The above code gives the $k^{th}$ permutation of the list which then can be used over a range.

```
 permutationChunk[list_, min_, max_] := 
 main[list, #] & /@ Range[min, max]
```

It works for the case you mentioned

```
 permutationChunk[{"t1", "t2", "t3"}, 3, 5]
 (*{{"t2", "t1", "t3"}, {"t2", "t3", "t1"}, {"t3", "t1", "t2"}}*)

permutationChunk[{"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", 
  "t9", "t10", "t11", "t12", "t13"}, 100000000, 100000000]
  (*{{"t1", "t12", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t11", "t13", "t9", "t2", "t7", "t3",
  "t8", "t10"}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The required functionality exists in the Combinatorica Package, loaded using Needs["Combinatorica`"].

The 3,000,000,000 th permutation of Range[13] is
`NthPermutation[3*10^9, Range[13]]`
`{7, 4, 2, 11, 3, 12, 1, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9, 13}`
and the inverse operation is
`RankPermutation[%]`
`3000000000`
Remark that the identity permutation has rank zero, not one.