# Generating permutations of at most 'n' elements, and where a specific subset of elements always appears

Tags: permutation

I often run into a situation where I'd like to generate a set of permutations with at most $n$ elements (here $n = 5$):

```
Permutations[{"t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11","t12","t13"}, 5]
```

I'd like to also specify that a specific subset of elements always appears in each subset (without generating the entire list of permutations and scanning through it, or scanning through the permutations in lexicographic order: [Generating a permutation of elements in chunks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69678/generating-a-permutation-of-elements-in-chunks)).  For example, could one generate a list of all length $n = 5$ permutations for the above example where the subset of elements `{"t2","t5","t7"}` always appears (in any order)?

Is there a (fast) way to ask Mathematica to do this?  One solution would be to ask for all length $q = 2$ subsets of `{"t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11","t12","t13"}`, concatenate these subsets with the list `{"t2","t5","t7"}`, generate the permutations for each subset, then concatenate each list of permutations.  However, is there maybe a nicer solution?

Comment: I think the only way to get the result is to pick the lists you want from the all Permutations[list,5]. It will be so easy this way. Something like this: Cases[allPermutations, x_ /; SubsetQ[x, {"t2","t5","t7"}]]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11", "t12", "t13"};
lAlways = {"t2", "t5", "t7"};

f[n_Integer, l_List, always_List] := 
                  Module[{lVar = Complement[l, always], toSel = n - Length@always}, 
                         Flatten[Permutations /@ (Join[always, #] & /@ Subsets[lVar, {toSel}]), 1]]
f[5, l, lAlways] // Length

(*5400*)

f[5, l, lAlways][[;; 5]] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Algohi's proposal but without SubsetQ so that it runs also in version 8.

```
list = {"t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10",
  "t11", "t12", "t13"};

list1 = {"t2", "t5", "t7"};

t = Permutations[list, {5}];
Length[t]
(* 154440  *)

t1= Select[t, Intersection[#, list1] == list1 &];

Length[t1 ]
(* 5400 *)

t1//Short
```

$\{\{\text{t1},\text{t2},\text{t3},\text{t5},\text{t7}\},\{\text{t1},\text{t2},\text{t3},\text{t7},\text{t5}\},\{\text{t1},\text{t2},\text{t4},\text{t5},\text{t7}\},\{\text{t1},\text{t2},\text{t4},\text{t7},\text{t5}\},\{\text{t1},\text{t2},\text{t5},\text{t3},\text{t7}\},\langle\langle 5391\rangle\rangle ,\{\text{t13},\text{t12},\text{t5},\text{t2},\text{t7}\},\{\text{t13},\text{t12},\text{t5},\text{t7},\text{t2}\},\{\text{t13},\text{t12},\text{t7},\text{t2},\text{t5}\},\{\text{t13},\text{t12},\text{t7},\text{t5},\text{t2}\}\}$

Best regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: The OP specifically stated _"(without generating the entire list of permutations and scanning through it)"_. I believe this solution is doing exactly that :)

Comment: @belisarius: you are right, I neglected the condition "without generating the entire list ...", but I simply wanted to make Algohi's proposal running in V8. BTW you didn't object to his comment. BTW2: your solution  shows that Algohi was wrong in stating that his is the "only way".

Comment: I've never seen a problem with only one possible solution in Mathematica :)

Comment: @belisarius: that's what I was saying.