# Want to compute the permutations of {1, 2, ..., 11} with only 3 GB of memory

Tags: memory, permutation

There is another way to calculate

```
Permutations [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}]
```

without triggering an error, I have 3 GB of RAM with WIN 7

Edit:

**This short code is the one that broke my head for a while, are 11 variables that must meet a very specific condition, their difference must be 1.
either can take the 11 values, hence all permutations, this code is an adaptation of another code I saw here, which helps me to what I need.**

```
juan[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_, j_, k_}] := 
 Abs[Differences /@ ({{a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}, {b, f}, {b, e}, {c, 
   e}, {c, f}, {c, g}, {d, f}, {d, g}, {e, b}, {e, a}, {e, f}, {e,
    i}, {e, h}, {f, g}, {f, j}, {f, i}, {f, h}, {g, i}, {g, 
   j}, {h, i}, {h, k}, {i, j}, {i, k}, {j, k}})] // Flatten
*(*per = Permutations[Range@11]*) (this line is calculated as 799    consecutive files in HD thanks to the collaboration of  rasher)
(*per=Import["C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\per.txt"]*)(as I upload the files   sequentially and that its securities are passing the variable "per" and will be prosecuted.?)
Select[per, FreeQ[juan@#, 1] &]
```

Comment: Do you need them "all at once"? `Combinatorica` package will generate them with incremental capability. A description of why you need this and what you'll do with it will help responses...

Comment: There are about 40,000,000 such permutations. What are you planning to do with them if you were able to compute them all?

Comment: I need only permutations to work with them a "txt" with someone who has more than 3GB would be great

Comment: @juanmuñoz: Well, that's going to be about 4500 pages in small print - I'm off to the office depot to get some print cartridges and paper... where shall I send it to? In all seriousness, *answering* the already asked questions of *what* you need to do will probably lead to more efficient means...

Comment: Probable duplicate: [(1283)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1283/121)

Comment: Well it takes 3.5 GB RAM on my computer, which has 4 GB RAM.  I suggest you buy some more RAM.

Comment: Reviewing the answers you have given me, running one now, thanks for now

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate because the Perumatations@Range@12 fails with an error message.  This is unrelated.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208926/2090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will write the permutations to `permutations.txt` in list blocks of ~50,000 each.

```
Quiet@Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica`"]]

len = 11
numchunk = 1000

chunks = Partition[Clip[FindDivisions[{0, len! - 1, 1}, numchunk],
                  {0, len! - 1}, {0,len! - 1}], 2, 1] // 
                  (# + Join[{{0, 0}}, ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length@# - 1]]) &;

Monitor[(chunk = #; (Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[#, 11] & /@ 
        Range @@ chunk) >> 
      "permutations-" <> ToString[First@#] <> "-" <> 
       ToString[Last@#] <> ".txt") & /@ chunks;, chunk]
```

Will take about an hour, I'd ventue...

If you must have equal sized files, you'll want to create your own `chunks`, since `FindDivisions` uses a heuristic that usually won't meet that criteria,
e.g. in your case for 11 length:

```
p = Partition[Range[1, 102089*392, 102089] - 1, 2, 1];
p[[1]] = p[[1]] - {0, 1};
p[[2 ;;, 1]] = p[[2 ;;, 1]] + 1;
chunks = p;
```

Will create files all with same # of permutations (about 100k).

Comment: processed at this time

Comment: You can modify the code to go save files sequentially, ie
per1.txt
per2.txt
..........
pern.txt , I got a "txt" of 2.5GB

Comment: I've noticed that the file is cut at the end, you know why this happens, not all permutations are recorded, if I could record each piece as a sequential files fixed size would be great

Comment: @juanmuñoz: I'll take a look - didn't miss any when tested...

Comment: @juanmuñoz: No, there's no problem. Unless the number of permutations is exactly divisible by # of chunks, there will be a different # of perms. in last result - but this gets them all. I updated it so you can control length of perms. and number of chunks, you can take it from there. Each chunk will create a file "Permutations-x-y.txt" where x and y are start and end chunk values. Note it will overwrite any existing file with same name(s).

Comment: Rasher thanks for all your help, edit the question up a bit so you know because I need all these permutations.
Although I tried not get my code sequentially read files and pass them to the variable "per" for calculation. My English is not my forte, sorry

Answer (score 0):

This will generate it in ~300 MB chunks.  Takes about 30 seconds.  You can work out what to do with the chunks.

```
Do[
 chunk = Prepend[#, i] & /@
   Permutations[
    DeleteCases[Range@11, i]
   ];
 doSomethingWithChunk[chunk],
 {i, 11}];
```

Comment: doSomethingWithChunk , this instruction mark me error , any idea?

Comment: It's called pseudocode.  You need to write your own function.  E.g. `sendChunkToMyFriend`.

Comment: Can you help me build the function, I am new at this

Comment: No, as the original comments indicate you are almost certainly approaching this problem inefficiently. Mathematica is not the right tool for this job.