# Calculating partial binary `Permutations`

Tags: combinatorics, algorithm, permutation

I would like *MMA* to only calculate *some* of the permutations of a set. I am currently doing something along the lines of

```
Permutations[Flatten[{Array[1 &, #], Array[0 &, # (# - 1)]}, 1]] &@3
```

and using `Take` and `Drop` before performing further calculation on smaller set.

For $n=3$ as above, this is fine, but since hte above calculation gives ${n^2}\choose{n}$ different permutations, asking *MMA* to calculate anything above $n=6$ results in `SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`.

I don't know the algorithm used to calculate `Permutations`, but is there any way of calculating and returning only permutations between `x` and `y`?

Comment: the `Combinatorica` package has a function called `NextPermutation`

Comment: @happyfish ...only problem is, I dont know what previous permutation was! - should work for `x==1`, but not for say, $1000$ permutations around `x==n^2`.

Comment: I thought you can iterate over x, but never mind, you can try `UnrankPermutation`, it looks more suitable here,

Comment: @happyfish unsure how to impliment. Trying `UnrankPermutation[3, 
   Flatten[{Array[1 &, #], Array[0 &, # (# - 1)]}, 1]] &@3` but nothing much happening

Comment: things like `UnrankPermutation[#, {0, 0, 1}] & /@ Range[2, 4]`, but it will be a problem if you worry about duplicates, since the algorithm used for this function and `NextPermutation` does not remove duplicates

Comment: @happyfish, yes, this seems to be the problem - so for $n=7$, I'm looking at $49!$ permutations instead of ${n^2}\choose{n}$ - quite a big difference!

Comment: I will try to write an algorithm

Comment: @happy fish - thanks :)

Comment: @happyfish I think this question could be considered a duplicate of [(1283)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1283/121).  If it is closed as such I think it should be merged to move your answer to that Q&A.  What do you think of this?  martin, same question for you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm not sure it is since the answer is specific to binary permutations. I have reworded the title to reflect that. In principle though, I have no objection to your proposal if it is closed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problem. Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: martin, I missed the fact that this was specific to binary permutations.  Thank you for editing the title. @happyfish No, nothing you need to do; thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will only work for binary permutations

```
permutationChunk[total_, select_, start_, end_] := 
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, total], Thread[# -> 1]] & /@ 
  Subsets[Range[total], {select}, {start, end}]
```

`total` is the length of the list, `select` is the number of 1s. You will have to know the total number of permutations, and then input `start` and `end` to get specific range of permutations.

For example,

```
Sort@permutationChunk[9, 3, 1, Binomial[9, 3]] == 
   Sort@Permutations[
     Flatten[{Array[1 &, #], Array[0 &, # (# - 1)]}, 1]] &@3
(*True*)
```

Comment: this is great - just what I was after! many thnaks :)

Comment: you're welcome.